# create a self-contained source?

Tags: document-classes

Is there a simple way to export a self-contained source for a large LaTeX document?  I would like it to export all of the class files, etc as well as the sources that I have written in order to create a self-contained source.

Comment: see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528/style-class-tutorials

Comment: Perhaps consider following some of the organizational ideas listed in [How do you store all your TeX files long-term?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42052/5764)

Answer (score 5):

LaTeX offers the environment `filecontents` and `filecontents*` which allow you to  add external files to your `.tex` file. The environments have to be used **before** the `\documentclass` declaration. If you process the `.tex` file the files are then written to the local directory (but only if there isn't already a file with that name) and thus can be used as part of the document.

Example:

```
\begin{filecontents}{myarticle.cls}
\LoadClass{article}
... my changes ...
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{myarticle}
```

The `filecontents` environment writes a short header (behind `%` signs at the top of the generated file, the star form suppresses that header. The latter is useful if you want to generate a file that needs to be kept unchanged. What is not possible is to add real binary files to your document in that way (e.g., a `.jpg` graphic).

Comment: In a pinch, you could uuencode a jpg graphic. Also, packages snapshot and bundledoc may offer some automation.

Comment: Thanks!  I may not have asked the right question, so please let me rephrase.  I have, directly and indirectly, used quite a few packages in the source of my book.  I want to have TeX export all the packages that I used so that I have a self-contained source to send to the publisher.  Is this feasible?  I can trace everything down by hand, presumably, but this would be very tedious.

Comment: LaTeX has `\listfiles` that gives you at least the list of all files used (I think there also a few scripts around to then collect them from the file system and put them into a zip or the like)

Comment: @Koji sure but you can also put everything in a zip :-) the point is that it normally runs without any manual steps and unless you use system extensions and have a uudecode handy such an encoded file can't be directly used

Comment: If you include `\usepackage{filecontents}` then the files will be overwritten. This is very useful when composing test cases so that the file on disk is always the latest version.