# How to share packages

Tags: miktex, installing, collaboration

I have locally created a document and used some packages for that. Is it possible to share this environment with my colleagues, without having them to install miktex and the packages?

Solved:

I used the portable version of miktex (http://miktex.org/portable) and put it to a shared networkfolder. After installing all required packages, all of my team mates are able to compile the document without problems.

Comment: Try `sharelatex` and it's server based system.

Comment: I don't think this works for my company as it is online... but thank you!

Comment: I think, this question is misleading: You are not sharing packages, it is in my point of view  rather a collection of `\usepackage{A}...\usepackage{Z}` commands within your document -- or do you have selfdefined commands?

Comment: Yes that's true. It's just the installed packages I want to share...

Comment: @markusw: This assumes, that your colleagues have the same packages on their system...

Comment: I think the packages are mainly .sty and .cls files that can be included into the folder of the .tex file that you want to share. That should get rid of the need to install them. Miktex may be portable but is a bit large... You might want to search for "self contained latex" stuff like [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47909/create-a-self-contained-source)

Comment: Ok I solved this by using http://miktex.org/portable and put it into a shared folder... Thank you everyone

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP solved it in the comments.

Comment: than why is it off topic?

Comment: @markusw: You solved it already, no other answer can solve it too (apart from repeating your comment ;-)) That's off-topic

Comment: @ChristianHupfer They can answer their own question.

Comment: @percusse: I will not hinder him ;-)

Comment: @markusw The floor is yours. Please give us a little bit more detailed answer so that others can benefit.