# I am trying to email a .tex file that uses \includegraphic? HELP?

Tags: graphics

I am trying to email a .tex file that uses \includegraphics. The file compiles on my computer but does not compile on the computer of the person I am emailing because of the \includegraphics. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: You should email the graphic with the `.tex` file, and place both in your working folder for the recipient to compile it. Alternatively, include *everything* as part of the PDF. For that see [How do you store all your TeX files long-term?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42052/5764)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. As it stands, your question is very terse. People here would need additional details in order to help you...

Comment: Werner, How do I place my graphic into my working folder?

Comment: Just copy the file into the same directory where the `.tex` file is.  Also: you can create an archive (`zip`, `tar`, etc.) that includes both the `.tex` and image file and just mail that...

Comment: If the graphics file is in another folder, then the `\includegraphics` command probably has the path as well (unless the document contains a `\graphicspath` command). So this advice is not accurate: @Jerry should email the `.tex` file as well as all images that it contains in `\includegraphics` commands, and the recipient should put them in the same (hopefully relative) paths. Of course, the easiest (and most probable) thing to do is to have everything in one folder (for small-scale documents).

Comment: @nplatis The advice is fine. So long as the recipient has the image in the same directory, LaTeX will find it regardless of whether there is a `\graphicspath` specified or not. The only problem would be if the `\includegraphics` command itself specified a relative or absolute path rather than just the filename of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the computer where the perseon is opening your tex file has graphics package installed. In Fedora Linux when using texlive for example it is necessary to have the teclive-graphics, which can be installed via YUM.

rememebr that this is a similar case to send a tex file without dependencies such as a document class when writing a conference paper.

For further help please give more contextual information about your problem and maybe some excerpts fo the problematic code and error output from compilation.