# Embedding LaTex code in pdf

Tags: pdf

Basically what I would like is a possibility to copy-paste the LaTeX code of a formula from a PDF document (that has been created with LaTeX), for using it in another LaTeX document. Is this possible?

I'm not aquainted enough with the pdf format to know if this is feasible, I was thinking along the lines of the Text underlay archived works use.

Edit:
What I was thinking of was something similar to [MathJax](http://mathjax.org)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). When asking questions it is better to provide a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) both in order to demonstrate what you are trying to do and to help others help you. This saves everyone time:)

Comment: This doesn't really have a proper working example though, as it's more of a conceptual question.

Comment: there's been some discussion about this, although mostly directed toward making pdf documents accessible to visually impaired readers.  for one such question, see [LaTeX accessibility](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19279/579) and also search for the tag "accessibilty".

Comment: Yes and no - you're right in that it doesn't need a `\documentclass` etc. On the other hand, what sort of text do you want to cut and paste? Certainly plan text is fine. Mathematics less so. More detail in your question wouldn't hurt:). The answer is probably no, however, as the PDF file doesn't keep track of the formatting...

Comment: @barbarabeeton unfortunately, the question is two years old, so one can't tell what the state-of-the-art is.

Comment: ross moore, of macquarie university, has been working on this for years; he has presented updates at four of the last five tug meetings, but unfortunately, much of this didn't get into tugboat.  his 2011 presentation is available as a video: [Further advances toward Tagged PDF for mathematics](http://river-valley.zeeba.tv/further-advances-toward-tagged-pdf-for-mathematics/); this year's presentation was also video'ed, and should appear on the same web site in due time.

Comment: @lines Are you trying to embed a listing, like listings package does?

Comment: This may help - it's not quite clear to me just what you want. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167714/writing-source-code-in-latex-as-text/167769#167769

Comment: The PDF specification allows for file attachments. You could attach a `.tex` to the PDF so you can open and copy-and-paste. See [How do you store all your TeX files long-term?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42052/5764)

Comment: @Werner I really want something as intuitive, or even more, than MathJax. I store all my Tex files in source control, but this is about sharing it with other people.

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate of [Making equations copyable in pdf](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119713/making-equations-copyable-in-pdf). Yes it is conceptual question, but you could still provide a MWE as an example with one or two equations and the type of code you'd like to be able to cut and paste.

Comment: Why don't you share the source?

Comment: @cfr I don't have source.

Comment: Then I don't understand. If you don't have the source, how are you going to make whatever-it-is copy-paste-able?

Comment: I don't have a source I want to make copy-paste-able as of now. It could be any code. I'd have the source at that point.

Comment: Please check out this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119713/making-equations-copyable-in-pdf