# Organizing an "input" file over time

Tags: input

I have a file I call `Packages.tex` that I put all the macros I use for a generic document in.

I've found that this file gets rather bloated, and when I do remove elements of it I don't use anymore, it will cause compilation errors on my previous documents. Usually at that point I only care about the .pdf so this isn't an issue, but it'd be nice to have a better option that leaves me with a .tex file that compiles well, without either having a bloated Packages.tex or having to resort to having multiple versions of it (so Packagesv1.tex, Packagesv2.tex, etc).

Does anybody have a good solution for managing an evolving file of macros with past documents?

Comment: This is [one way](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116797/8528). (Off-topic: don't call it `Packages.tex`. Use the `.sty` extension, and load it like a regular package with `\usepackage`.)

Comment: Related: [How do you store all your TeX files long-term?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42052/5764)

Comment: Perhaps compile and embed your `Packages.tex` using [`embedfile`](http://ctan.org/pkg/embedfile). This will keep the existing files that compile into the output PDF as part of a singular package. If you're interested in re-compiling, the files are stored with the PDF.

Comment: Version control is another option. Not a replacement for the other suggestions, but maybe more or less suitable depending on what you need. (And version control is good anyway, of course.)

Comment: @cfr I have rudimentary version control, but I was hoping to get something so if someone wants one of my old documents I can just zip it up from my local machine "without thinking" about it/needing to mess with GIT.

Comment: @Werner, do you know if there are any limitations to file size and file extension that can be embedded in a PDF? (I just went through the manual you linked and couldn't find such information)