# How to create Candle Symbol in LaTeX

Tags: symbols

I have a need to insert a candle symbol in "elite" in the place of "i". 
I browsed through the [comprehensive LaTeX symbols pdf](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) and could not find any one matching up. 
Is there any easy way to achieve this? An image processing tool is always a way but I wanted to see if LaTeX has any solutions for it.

Comment: Related questions: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13594/how-to-add-a-custom-symbol-to-latex .

Comment: How about some symbol stacking with `\sun` and `\i`?

Comment: or the candle from [How can I draw a cake using tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42598/how-can-i-draw-a-cake-using-tikz)

Comment: or a candle from a [Christmas tree](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39149/how-can-we-draw-a-christmas-tree-with-decorations-using-tikz)

Comment: Quite apart from the fact that this has received fantastic answers, this is one case where I think that detexify might not have worked: I'd love to see how to draw a candle in detexify sufficiently precisely that it doesn't look like a deformed `i`.

Comment: @Aku: I just noticed that the middle three letters of “elite” are “lit” and that the last four letters are “lite”, and that there is also the visual pun “e-lite”, e.g., “electronic light.” I am curious—what is this for? It's certainly an interesting use for a candle, and the coincidence with “lit” has me especially intrigued now.

Comment: a friend of mine asked me about this, I was naive enough to post on forum, I should have change that to "Light" is it possible to change to light now since my friend wanted this to be his company logo. he told me that it was stupid on my part and now he can not use it, i feel really sad

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Here is a custom-designed Bezier-curve flame in TikZ combined with a dotless letter ‘i’:

[image: candle examples]

Here is the source:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\iflame}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#1]
    \fill[color=#2]
      (0,0) .. controls (-1.5,1.25) and (.5,2) .. (-.2,4)
            .. controls (1,2.5) and (1,.5) .. (0,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\icandle}[1]{%
  \rlap{\kern-.0275em\raisebox{1.2ex}{\iflame{.035}{#1}}}$\i$%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
el\icandle{red}te\\
el\icandle{orange}te\\
el\icandle{yellow!80!red}te\\
el\icandle{gray}te\\
elite\\
\par

\end{document}
```

If you find the serifs on the ‘i’ to be undesirable, you can substitute instead a vertical rule of height 1ex, depth 0ex, and width .7pt, with about .09em kerning on each side, and then lower the flame by .1ex.  I tried it both ways and I personally like it better with the serifs on the ‘i’.

**Addendum**

I just noticed today that the middle three letters of “elite” are “lit” and that the last four letters are “lite”. There is also the visual pun “e-lite”, e.g., “electronic light.”

Comment: Well then, this makes my little `\sun` loose some of its shine...

Comment: Aren't you a graphic designer? Because that logo is really terrific!

Comment: Just brilliant. Is it better to say `cycle` instead of `..(0,0)` in the end of the curve?

Comment: Awesome, You guys are all "THE BEST". thanks for all your help.

Comment: Nice choice of design.

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen `cycle` only works with lines, so you can say `-- cycle` but it doesn't work with curves.  As the path is filled, it is closed anyway so it doesn't make a difference to the final rendering.

Comment: Excellent!! One suggestion: if you change the definition of `iflame` to  use `fill[#2]` instead, then the options passed to `icandle` would be standard `tikz` options so other parameters could be passed in if so desired. For example: `\icandle[color=red, opacity=0.5]` etc. One could even specify a draw color different than a fill color.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Ah yes, I like that idea. One thing to note: It's important here *not* to use a draw color (only fill color) as drawing a border significantly increases the size, while also exposing a path-cycle flaw at (0,0) in this implementation (not present in fill-only mode). If there were a way to stroke the path on the interior only, that might work.

Comment: Yes, but the thickness of the draw color can be controlled. Not that I am recommending it, up to the user to do what they want. This is already possible using what you have, but requires that the first parameter be a color, and saying `[red,opacity=0.5]` does not quite seem right.

Comment: @ToddLehman You can stroke the path on the interior only by clipping against itself first (requires specifying the path twice).

Answer (score 17):

Here is a text-based "candle", obtained by stacking `\sun` (from [`wasysym`](http://ctan.org/pkg/wasysym)) on top of `\i` using the [`accents` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/wasysym). Some scaling is provided by `\scalebox` from [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx). It even scales based on the font selection (like `\large`, `\Large`, ...).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{wasysym}% http://ctan.org/pkg/wasysym
\usepackage{accents}% http://ctan.org/pkg/accents
\newcommand{\sunI}{\ensuremath{\accentset{\scalebox{.5}{\sun}}{\mbox{\i}}}}%
\begin{document}
elite~el\sunI te
\end{document}​
```

I'm not sure how candle-ish of a look you're after... `:-|`

Comment: Werner - That would work great for me, however there is always room for improvement. So I hope other people keep posting good suggestions. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 12):

By adjusting the vertical postion of the symbols, I think that this can work:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{accents}
\newcommand{\candle}{\ensuremath{\accentset{\scalebox{.5}{\(\varspadesuit\)}}{\scalebox{.6}{\(\talloblong\)}}}}
\begin{document}
elite el\candle{}te
\end{document}
```

[image: candle]

Answer (score 12):

As there is a unicode for this in version 7.0, I present a pure symbols solution with the only available font I could find.

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand*{\candle}{{\fontspec{symbola.ttf}\symbol{"1F56F}}}

\begin{document}
   el\candle te
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There's a `\Candle` symbol in [`tikzsymbols`](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzsymbols/tikzsymbols.pdf) package.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\begin{document}
    \Candle
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

*A word of caution:* I notice the *flame* is not exactly aligned.

Comment: @Werner Do you know name of the *cotton rope* thing in between the wax and flame (English is not my first language :P)?

Comment: It's called a [candle wick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candle_wick).