# Drawing a flag with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to create a flag in TikZ but aesthetically it's not the best. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
%\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols,shapes.misc}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.25,transform shape]
\draw[rounded corners=0.1pt] (0,2) rectangle (0.2,4);
\node[tape, draw,right] at (0.32,3.55) {\vphantom{\large i}\hphantom{TEST}};
%\draw[xshift=0.25cm](0,4) -- (1,4) -- (2,3) -- (3,2) -- (2,2) -- (1,2) -- (0,2) -- (0,4)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% or%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.00mm, y=1.00mm, inner xsep=0pt, inner ysep=0pt, outer xsep=0pt, outer ysep=0pt]
\path[line width=0mm] (138.71,542.78) rectangle +(14.34,14.44);
\definecolor{L}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\path[line width=0.30mm, draw=L] (140.71,555.13) [rotate around={270:(140.71,555.13)}] rectangle +(10.35,1.73);
\path[line width=0.30mm, draw=L] (142.93,554.82);
\path[line width=0.30mm, draw=L] (142.98,549.72) .. controls (142.98,549.72) and (142.98,549.72) .. (142.98,549.72) .. controls (142.99,551.40) and (143.07,553.03) .. (143.01,554.75) .. controls (143.00,554.94) and (142.98,555.18) .. (143.11,555.20) .. controls (144.51,555.37) and (146.55,554.72) .. (147.61,553.60) .. controls (148.77,552.38) and (150.28,551.53) .. (150.87,552.64) .. controls (151.02,552.93) and (151.94,548.83) .. (147.57,549.33) .. controls (146.00,549.51) and (144.56,549.84) .. (142.98,549.72) -- cycle;
\path[line width=0.30mm, draw=L] (147.56,553.67) -- (147.53,549.33);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The second is drawn with TpX. The display are not the best. Maybe a flag like the one shown here in [tex.stackexchange.com](http://tex.stackexchange.com) would suffice.

[image]

I am really just looking for a neat representation of a flag which I can scale. This flag will be displayed like an icon on my Lecture Notes for important milestones in certain topics.

Comment: The TikZ/PSTricks based [bclogo](http://texdoc.net/pkg/bclogo) package has a lot of cliparts for this kind of purposes. You might modify any flags if the country is not available or you have your own country in mind :) Your French might be better than my TikZsh (?!).

Comment: Any reason it has to be in TikZ?  You can find lots of [flags on openclipart.org](http://openclipart.org/tags/flag), download SVG, open in inkscape, edit, save as PDF.

Comment: There's also `\Flag` and `\VarFlag` from the `ifsym` package. Yet another source of flag icons is [The Noun Project](http://thenounproject.com/noun/flag/), which has seven different flags.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I just love TikZ, :-). It can be in Pstricks too.

Comment: @doncherry Can use freely and edit the documents at the site you shared? The ideas are great.

Comment: @azetina: It depends: At the Noun Project, two flags are CC0 (No rights reserved), the rest are CC BY 3.0. As for `ifsym`, you'll have to check the documentation.

Answer (score 39):

A black flag but it's easy to change the form or the colors

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}[rotate=10]
    \begin{scope}[every path/.style={fill=black}]
        \draw (-.2,0) to [bend right] (.2,0) -- (.2,8) to [bend left] (-.2,8) -- cycle;
        \draw (0,8) circle (.4) ;
    \draw [rounded corners] (.2,7.6) to [out=60 ,in=180] (3,8) to [out=0, in = 200] (8,9) to [out=-85 ,in=85] (7.5,4) to [out=220,in=0](5,3) to [out=180,in=10] (.2,3) to [out =85,in=-80]  (.2,7.6) ; 
\end{scope}
\end{scope}  
\end{tikzpicture} 
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}[rotate=10,scale=.5]
    \begin{scope}[every path/.style={shade, top color=black,bottom color=darkgray}]
        \draw (-.2,0) to [bend right] (.2,0) -- (.2,8) to [bend left] (-.2,8) -- cycle;
        \draw (0,8) circle (.4) ;
    \draw [rounded corners] (.2,7.6) to [out=60 ,in=180] (3,8) to [out=0, in = 200] (8,9) to [out=-85 ,in=85] (7.5,4) to [out=220,in=0](5,3) to [out=180,in=10] (.2,3) to [out =85,in=-80]  (.2,7.6) ; 
\end{scope}
\end{scope}  
\end{tikzpicture} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]

\begin{scope}[rotate=10]
    \begin{scope}[every path/.style={fill=black}]
        \draw (-.2,0) to [bend right] (.2,0) -- (.2,8) to [bend left] (-.2,8) -- cycle;
        \draw (0,8) circle (.4) ;
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\clip [rounded corners] (.2,7.6) to [out=60 ,in=180] coordinate[pos=.95] (h1) (3,8) to [out=0, in = 200]  coordinate[pos=.5] (h2) (8,9) coordinate(h3) to [out=-85 ,in=85] (7.5,4) coordinate(b3) to [out=220,in=0] coordinate[pos=.85] (b2)(5,3)  to [out=180,in=10]  coordinate[pos=.5] (b1)(.2,3) to [out =85,in=-80]  (.2,7.6) ;
\fill[blue] (-1,9) -- (h1) to[out=-85,in=80] (b1) -- (0,0) --cycle;     
\fill[red] (h2) to[out=-85,in=80] (b2) -- ++(0,-0.75) -- ([yshift=-1.25]b3) --(b3) to  [out=85 ,in=-85]  (h3) -- cycle  ; 
\end{scope} 
\draw[thick] [rounded corners] (.2,7.6) to [out=60 ,in=180] coordinate[pos=.95] (h1) (3,8) to [out=0, in = 200]  coordinate[pos=.5] (h2) (8,9) coordinate(h3) to [out=-85 ,in=85] (7.5,4) coordinate(b3) to [out=220,in=0] coordinate[pos=.85] (b2)(5,3)  to [out=180,in=10]  coordinate[pos=.5] (b1)(.2,3) to [out =85,in=-80]  (.2,7.6) ;      
\draw[thick]  (h1) to[out=-85,in=80] (b1); 
\draw[thick]  (h2) to[out=-85,in=80] (b2);  
\end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very pretty and sober drawing.

Comment: @azetina I added a flag with color because its not very easy to add color with  this kind of flag

Comment: Very much appreciated. I will study what you have and learn a bit more on the curved paths.

Answer (score 31):

How about this:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\flagscalefactor}{0.2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\flagrotationdegree}{45}
\newcommand{\flagpolecolor}{brown!60!black}
\newcommand{\flagcolor}{yellow!67!red}
\newcommand{\flagsymbol}{:)}
\newcommand{\flagsymbolcolor}{black}

\newcommand{\tikzflag}{%
    \begin{scope}[scale=\flagscalefactor,rotate=\flagrotationdegree]
        \draw[fill=\flagpolecolor,thick] (0,0) -- ++ (0,8) arc (180:0:0.4 and 0.1) -- ++ (0,-8) arc (360:180:0.4 and 0.1);
        \draw[thick] (0,8) arc (180:360:0.4 and 0.1);
        \draw[fill=\flagcolor,thick] (0.8,7.5) to[out=-30,in=210] ++(3,0) to[out=30,in=150] ++ (3,0) -- ++ (0,-3) to [out=150,in=30] ++(-3,0) to[out=210,in=-30] ++(-3,0) -- cycle;
        \node[\flagsymbolcolor] at (3.8,6) {\textbf{\flagsymbol}};
    \end{scope}
}

\newcommand{\questionflag}{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\flagscalefactor}{0.2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\flagrotationdegree}{22.5}
    \renewcommand{\flagpolecolor}{brown!60!black}
    \renewcommand{\flagcolor}{yellow}
    \renewcommand{\flagsymbol}{?}
    \renewcommand{\flagsymbolcolor}{red}
    \tikzflag
}

\newcommand{\importantflag}{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\flagscalefactor}{0.2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\flagrotationdegree}{-22.5}
    \renewcommand{\flagpolecolor}{brown!60!black}
    \renewcommand{\flagcolor}{green!50!blue}
    \renewcommand{\flagsymbol}{!}
    \renewcommand{\flagsymbolcolor}{white}
    \tikzflag
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzflag
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\questionflag
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\importantflag
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Firt I made a general command `\tikzflag` that can be altered in several ways, then I made some specialized commands from it. Like that you can easily 'flag' questions, problems, hints etc.
Here's the result:

[image]

---

**Edit 1:** Here is a more usable implementation. The `\marker` command is from some question around here, I don't recall were it originated from. It is used to define the positions the flags should go to. The names of the flags should be unique, otherwise a flag might end up at a previous position. As this uses the `overlay, remember picture` option, it will take two runs to work properly.

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\marker}[2]{% name, shift
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture] 
        {\node (m-#1) at (#2) {};}%
}        

\pgfmathsetmacro{\flagscalefactor}{0.3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\flagrotationdegree}{45}
\newcommand{\flagpolecolor}{brown!60!black}
\newcommand{\flagcolor}{yellow!67!red}
\newcommand{\flagsymbol}{:)}
\newcommand{\flagsymbolcolor}{black}
\newcommand{\flagadditionalcommands}{}

\newcommand{\tikzflag}[1][0,0]{% shift
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\flagscalefactor,rotate=\flagrotationdegree,shift={(#1)},overlay,remember picture]
        \draw[fill=\flagpolecolor,thick] (0,0) -- ++ (0,8) arc (180:0:0.4 and 0.1) -- ++ (0,-8) arc (360:180:0.4 and 0.1);
        \draw[thick] (0,8) arc (180:360:0.4 and 0.1);
        \draw[fill=\flagcolor,thick] (0.8,7.5) to[out=-30,in=210] ++(3,0) to[out=30,in=150] ++ (3,0) -- ++ (0,-4.5) to [out=150,in=30] ++(-3,0) to[out=210,in=-30] ++(-3,0) -- cycle;
        \node[\flagsymbolcolor,fill=white,circle,thick,inner sep=1pt,draw,thin] (a) at (3.8,5.25) {\textbf{\flagsymbol}};
        \flagadditionalcommands
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\questionflag}[1]{% name
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\flagscalefactor}{0.1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\flagrotationdegree}{22.5}
    \renewcommand{\flagpolecolor}{brown!60!black}
    \renewcommand{\flagcolor}{yellow}
    \renewcommand{\flagsymbol}{\tiny ?}
    \renewcommand{\flagsymbolcolor}{black}
    \marker{#1}{-0.8,-0.8}
    \tikzflag[m-#1]
}

\newcommand{\importantflag}[1]{% name
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\flagscalefactor}{0.1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\flagrotationdegree}{-22.5}
    \renewcommand{\flagpolecolor}{brown!60!black}
    \renewcommand{\flagcolor}{red!50!orange}
    \renewcommand{\flagsymbol}{\tiny !}
    \renewcommand{\flagsymbolcolor}{black}
    \marker{#1}{-1.1,-0.6}
    \tikzflag[m-#1]
}

\newcommand{\hintflag}[1]{% name
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\flagscalefactor}{0.1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\flagrotationdegree}{0}
    \renewcommand{\flagpolecolor}{brown!60!black}
    \renewcommand{\flagcolor}{blue!50!cyan}
    \renewcommand{\flagsymbol}{\tiny $\blacktriangledown$}
    \renewcommand{\flagsymbolcolor}{black}
    \marker{#1}{-0.9,-0.6}
    \tikzflag[m-#1]
}

\begin{document}

\questionflag{first}\lipsum[1]

\hintflag{firstmath}\[ \int\limits_0^11dx=1 \]

\importantflag{second}\lipsum[2]

\importantflag{secondmath}
\begin{align*}
    0 &= x^2 +px +q\\
    x_{_{1/2}}   &= -\frac{p}{2} \pm \sqrt{\left(\frac{p}{2}\right)^2-q}
\end{align*}

\hintflag{third}\lipsum[43]

\questionflag{firstpicture} \\ \includegraphics[scale=7]{avatar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice....Outstanding results. I just didn't get the understanding of the curved paths. Am getting their though.

Comment: The `to` operation will draw a possibly curved line between two points. If you specify a plain `to` it will draw a sraight line (like `--`). If you specify `in=degrees` or `out=degrees` the line will enter or leave the points at that angle. Via `looseness` you can specify how 'narrow' the curve will be, which is [illustrated here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44777/plotting-a-curve-with-given-values-and-derivative-values/44899#44899)

Comment: The official name is `\tikzmark` for that ;)