# Error message with hobby package

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, hobby

I am trying to use the `hobby`package with this minimal example from the manual:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5,use Hobby shortcut]
\draw (0,0) .. (6,4) .. (4,9) .. (1,7) .. (3,5) .. cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

On compiling with `pdflatex` I get this error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\hobby_genpath: ...y }\prg_stepwise_function:nnnN 
                                                  {0}{1}{\l_hobby_npoints_in...
l.7 .... (6,4) .. (4,9) .. (1,7) .. (3,5) .. cycle
                                                  ;
```

I am using TeXLive 2012 and the `hobby.code.tex` that came with it.

What can I do to get it working?

P.S. Googling came up with a message on the [Italian TeX Group forum](http://www.guitex.org/home/en/forum/5-tex-e-latex/83195-la-libreria-hobby-tikz-non-funziona-piu) but I could not cotton on to what was being said.

Comment: Essentially, egreg in [this post](http://www.guitex.org/home/forum/5-tex-e-latex/83195-la-libreria-hobby-tikz-non-funziona-piu?lang=en#83203) explained that the function `\prg_stepwise_function:nnnN` has been substituted by `\int_step_function:nnnN`; I used the workaround suggested by him, for example, in my last edit to [How can I draw an egg using TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74168/how-can-i-draw-an-egg-using-tikz/74613#74613).

Comment: @Claudio Fiandrino: thanks for the explanation and that link: it was *real* fun!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fixed in the latest version of the `hobby` package.  Unfortunately, I didn't get it to CTAN in time for the TL freeze (8th April according to [TUG](http://www.tug.org/texlive/)) so if you use TeXLive you'll have to install it yourself from CTAN (or wait until TL2013 is released).  (MikTeX works differently, I believe.)

You can download the latest version directly from CTAN at [`hobby`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hobby).

Comment: Thanks a million for the `hobby` package and for the clarification. I have updated and tried it out. It works! The operative line in the minimal example should now be: `\draw [closed] (0,0) .. (6,4) .. (4,9) .. (1,7) .. (3,5);` to get the desired results.