# How can I draw a wave diagram in Tikz/PSTricks

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

Sorry for the undetailed title, I didn't know what to call this. How can I draw the image below in TiKz or PSTricks?

[image]

Comment: You can take the beautiful `controls` syntax from this one http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43739/how-to-create-candle-symbol-in-latex

Comment: Is it just a pulse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is recommended to use `standalone` document class for each diagram and compile it with either `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` or `xelatex`. The resulting output is a PDF file that you can import with `\includegraphics` into your main document.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-node}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-.5)(2,7)
    \psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none](0,0)(-2,0)(2,6.5)
    \psplot[algebraic,swapaxes]{0}{Pi 2 mul}{-sin(x)}
    \pscircle[fillstyle=solid](!0 Pi 2 mul){3pt}
    \pcline{->}(!0 Pi 2 div)(!-1 Pi 2 div)
    \naput{$r$}
    \pcline{->}(1,0)(1,1)
    \naput{$x$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Attenuated version:

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-node}
\def\f{-sin(x)*1.2^(-2*x)}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-.5)(2,7)
    \psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none](0,0)(-2,0)(2,6.5)
    \psplot[algebraic,swapaxes]{0}{Pi 2 mul}{\f}
    \pscircle[fillstyle=solid](!0 Pi 2 mul){3pt}
    \pcline{->}(!0 Pi 2 div)(!-.55 Pi 2 div)
    \naput{$r$}
    \pcline{->}(1,0)(1,1)
    \naput{$x$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I see you have utilized `-sin (x)` is it possible to have a lower amplitude at the beginning?

Comment: Did you mean the wave gets attenuated?

Comment: Yes, at beginning the wave is thinner and gradually it gets bigger. EDIT: I tried putting your code into an article class but it's not working.

Comment: See my edit on the top and bottom. It should be better to separate your code for diagrams from the main input file thereby your main input file becomes cleaner in addition to reducing the compilation time.

Answer (score 2):

An option using TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\draw (0,0) -- +(0,-7);
\draw (-1.5,-7) -- (1.5,-7);
\draw (0,-7) .. controls (-2,-5) and (1,-2) .. (0,-2pt);
\begin{scope}[myarrow/.style={single arrow,draw,inner sep=2pt,text width=#1,single arrow head extend=2.5pt,thin}]
\node[myarrow=5pt,label=below:$r$,xscale=-1] at (-0.3,-5) {};
\node[myarrow=12pt,label=above:$x$,rotate=90] at (0.8,-6.5) {};
\end{scope}
\fill[white,draw=black] (0,0) circle[radius=4pt];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]