# LaTeX Cartooning

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, animations

Are there any Latex packages (or any other text based methods) to assist in cartooning i.e. creation of simple images representing real-life objects. Something as simple as the images on xkcd is good enough for me.

(FYI - Randall Munroe does use the old school technique of putting pen/pencil on paper)

To provide a sharper focus to the original question [*above*] - I need a package with an assortment of shapes of commonly seen tangible objects, such as cars, laptops, trees etc., with multiple anchors to finely control the final 'look' of this shape. I was especially looking for stick human figures. The Shape library in the TikZ/PGF library comes the closest from amongst what I have already seen, but not close enough.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). I removed 'thanks' from your post since we omit this. Instead, you should [up-vote and accept the answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask), giving the answerer the site reputation.

Comment: I don't have a specific answer for you, but you might have a look at the [TikZ/PGF package](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-pgf). Some example of a tikz drawing can be found here: [How can I draw a cake using TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42598/how-can-i-draw-a-cake-using-tikz) or [TikZ and PGF examples](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/)

Comment: While not text-based, you might want to consider Inkscape. It has some good LaTeX features.

Comment: From what I have seen from amongst the answers I have received, the Shape library in the TikZ/PGF package comes closest to what I had in mind; and yet it is quite a way off from what I had in mind.

Comment: A (or multiple) stick figure shape(s) with multiple anchors would come a lot closer to  what I had in mind. Is there something like that or does it have to be created?

Comment: A package like this would be insanely useful. Too bad it doesn't seem to exist (yet?). The closest I've found is something for drawing [pigs](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/parameterised-pig/) but unfortunately I need people...

Answer (score 6):

| Thing | Package |
| --- | --- |
| Ducks | [TikZducks](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzducks) |
| Marmot | [TikZmarmot](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzmarmots) |
| Donkey | [I need a donkey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/312199/129388) |
| other animals, birds | [TikZlings](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzlings), [animal pond](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/387047/129388), `pst-fun` |
| vehicle | `pst-vehicle` |
| Lenny face | [Lenny face question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/308600/129388) |
| fruits & vegetables | [fruits question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/413389/129388) |
| bearwear | [bear wear](https://ctan.org/pkg/bearwear) |
| Humans | [tikzpeople](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpeople), [Custom “human” shape for tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84275/129388) especially [stickman](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/487863/129388) |
| bats | [halloweenmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/halloweenmath) (also maybe pumpkins, witches, ghosts, cats, and so on) |
| snowman | [scsnowman](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scsnowman) |
| turtles | [turtles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273473/129388) |
| rabbits | [rabbits question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/408898/129388) |
| fishes | [fish question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/361547/129388) |
| more different ducks | [top answers of ducks](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=358) |

[The question that probably started all of this.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63732/129388).

Answer (score 1):

Some math-related stuff

| Thing | Package |
| --- | --- |
| math hats | [real hats](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/realhats) |
| math transposes | [realtranspose](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/realtranspose) |

and some things I can't classify

- [batman logo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47388/129388)
- [cow font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115471/using-contexts-cow-font-with-pdftex)
- [How do I make my document look like it was written by a    Cthulhu-worshipping madman?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29402)
- [Create xkcd style diagram in TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74878/129388)

finally, watch the [fun](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fun) tag.