# Cute (child-friendly) document in LaTeX

Tags: document-classes, document-configuration, fun

My girlfriend is teacher at primary school, she's new using LaTeX and she needs to make a "cute document" for kids, but I don't know how change the following items to make them look nice for the kids:

- parts,
- sections,
- page number/number of pages
- and all this things to make a cute document.

Comment: What do you mean by cute?

Comment: This? http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/comicsans/

Comment: Finally, a counterpart to [How do I make my document look like it was written by a Cthulhu-worshipping madman?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29402). Well, we could always go for [Comic Sans](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29406/4012), as Seamus suggested.

Comment: You can use the [cow font](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb27-1/tb86hoekwater-cows.pdf). There is a typescript for context but I do not know if there is a latex package for it or not.

Comment: there's a thread on [using the cow font with pdfTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115471/using-contexts-cow-font-with-pdftex) now. Using it with other engines isn't too difficult; there might also be a little package in the near future.

Answer (score 181):

I made a humble attempt of a cute document with `memoir` and some Inkscape graphics. `:)` Please bear with me, after all, cuteness is in the eye of the beholder. `:)`

Spoiler alert:

> ! Don't laugh at my duck, please.

Jake and I were talking in the TeX and friends chatroom a few months ago about funny chapter styles for `memoir`. For the fun of it, we made a theme based on Super Mario Bros. I drew Mario and a goomba:

[image: Image 1]

Later, we added a feature that added as many goombas as the chapter number - Chapter 3 would have three goombas, and so on.

Jake made an awesome Yoshi code that extended his tongue to fill the line:

[image: Image 2]

Sadly, the code is not available, for obvious reasons: Nintendo wouldn't be happy. After all, those characters are copyrighted. What we did was just a humble case study of "different" styles for documents based on `memoir`.

That said, I think we could use some ideas from this "exercise". I drew two elements in Inkscape, a flower and a duck:

[image: Inkscape]

I then exported both images to a `tikzpicture` via a nice plugin called [`inkscape2tikz`](http://inkscape2tikz.googlecode.com/). This step is not mandatory, after all, we can simply print those images to a vector format - say, `.pdf` - and include them as images (it's way easier).

In order to make our lives easier, I created a new package called `duck`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{duck}[2012/18/07 Duck style for memoir]

\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{xspace}

\definecolor{cffffff}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\definecolor{cffcc00}{RGB}{255,204,0}
\definecolor{c008000}{RGB}{0,128,0}
\definecolor{caa8800}{RGB}{170,136,0}
\definecolor{cd4aa00}{RGB}{212,170,0}
\definecolor{ce6e6e6}{RGB}{230,230,230}

\newcommand{\drawduck}{%
  ... TikZ code here ...
}

\newcommand{\drawflower}{%
... TikZ code here ...
}

\newcounter{myflowers}

\newcommand{\flowers}[1]{%
\setcounter{myflowers}{-1}\loop\stepcounter{myflowers}\ifnum\value{myflowers} < #1 \drawflower\repeat%
}

\makechapterstyle{weloveducks}{%
\chapterstyle{default}
\renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\color{olive}\bfseries\HUGE}
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\hfill\bfseries\HUGE}
\renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\chapnamefont\thechapter\xspace\flowers{\thechapter}}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
\drawduck\bfseries\HUGE\hfill ##1%
}}
```

The TikZ code is huge. The full sample `duck.sty` file is available [here](https://gist.github.com/3136565).

Now, let's go to our `.tex` file. I opted to use a system font, so I went with `xelatex`. I don't like to change `\parskip`, `\parindent` and line spacing, but I thought that for this particular document, some adjustments would make the text easier to be read by a kid.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Segoe Print}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\usepackage{duck}

\begin{document}

\chapterstyle{weloveducks}

\setlength{\parskip}{1.5\baselineskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\OnehalfSpacing

\chapter{The journey begins}

Hi, I am a duck. Quack!

\kant[1]

\chapter{The journey continues}

\kant[2]

\chapter{The journey ends}

\kant[3]

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: Chapter 1]

---

[image: Chapter 3]

This is surely the most clumsy duck drawing ever in the history of duck drawing. `:)`

Note that the number of flowers grow together with the chapter counter. Kant text is provided by `kantlipsum`. And `memoir` is awesome, as always. `:)`

Hope you guys like it. `:)`

Comment: I will use this for my thesis.

Comment: That is one awesome duck! And it's so clever, too!

Comment: Where is the duck ? ;)

Comment: After seeing your solution, I know what "cute" means ;-) Nice job!

Comment: i will not laugh, but i don't think your duck can swim.  (as one knows from "peter and the wolf", ducks have to be able to swim.)  on the other hand, it can probably fly.  so i'd call it a birdie.  (again, cf. "peter and the wolf".)  definitely cute!!!

Comment: Kantian prose in a children's book is really interesting. :) But probably they can understand it better than Lorem Ipsum.

Comment: If it's a duck, it must be Paulo.

Comment: @kissmyarmpit Have you finished writing your thesis? Mind to share (I'm curious about the final look) :-)

Comment: @PauloCereda Beautiful, beautiful duck! You finally convinced me. You're definitely one of those gurus who add that light and special touch to TeX.sx `=)`

Comment: I wish there are a libary of animal icons in tikz so that we can use for more friendly documents.

Comment: ...and a built-in comic-sans type font...

Comment: @Thumbolt see https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzlings

Comment: `http://inkscape2tikz.googlecode.com/` is no longer working. Kindly update the link.