# Drawing a university logo

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I am very new to latex and need to draw a logo. Could anyone please help or show me how to draw this logo?

[image]

Comment: why draw it? why not include the official logo you have?

Comment: Do you really need to draw this *in* LaTeX? Can’t you simply include it as an image (PNG or PDF)?

Comment: I think that for this kind of drawing, some other tool might be better (faster results can be obtained with other tools). If you insist on using LaTeX for this, in [Draw a Coat of Arms in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79147/3954) you can find some initial ideas.

Comment: Apparently there are some "unofficial" vector versions of this coat of arms (University of Auckland). Personally, I'd use an official file provided by the university, probably a `.png` or similar.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing what you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Drawing that kind of picture isn't that easy (either using tikz or Pstricks). Maybe it will take a TON of time to produce a drawing similar than the one you have and probably, the professor or the one who sees that picture won't even realize about the difference. Better follow David's answer.

Comment: It seems the University of Auckland has several publishing style guides.  Contacting the appropriate department might get you the styles/graphics that you need.  See  [UOA Style Guide Search](http://search.auckland.ac.nz/search?q=style+guide&site=All_university_websites&btnG=Search&client=uoa_frontend&proxystylesheet=uoa_frontend&proxyreload=0&output=xml_no_dtd&headerQuickLinks=&sort=date%3AD%3AL%3Ad1&oe=UTF-8&ie=UTF-8&ud=1&exclude_apps=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try **tikzedt** http://www.tikzedt.org/ TikzEdt is a combined WYSIWYG/text editor designed for editing Tikz code.

Answer (score 12):

You should be able to obtain a scalable image to include from your University, but even a png will do, such as the low resolution image in your question, which may be used as

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[height=100pt]{cs5KC}

write stuff here write stuff here write stuff here 
write stuff here write stuff here write stuff here 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you can find a true eps version of the logo from the University services, you may want to convert it to `pgf` using the [eps2pgf](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/eps2pgf/) converter. `true` here means "vector graphics".

Comment: Although, unless you want to edit it, PDF will always be faster.