# How can I change the shape of nodes (boxes) into some other shape?

Tags: tcolorbox, genealogytree, genealogy

I would like to draw the family tree by using `genealogytree` package. I have no idea how to change the shape of nodes from simple box to something more complicated, for example coat of arms. Always, the box is rectangle. So my question is how to change it to something else. Thank you for your help and tips.

I tried to do it through `tcbset`, but every attempt failed. So, I'm afraid it will be not the correct way.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}    
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}    
\usepackage{incgraph} 
\usepackage{tikz,pgf}

\begin{document}
\begin{inctext}
\begin{tikzpicture}    
    \genealogytree[template=signpost]{
    parent{           
           c[female]{Silvie Polaková} 
           g[male]{Alex Homola}  
           parent{
                  g[male]{Radomir Palacek}         
                 } 
           parent{   
                  c[female]{Marie Homolova}
                  g[female]{Zdenka Homolova}                  
                  parent{
                         g[female]{Marie Drastichova}
                        }
                  parent{
                         c[female]{Marie Homolova}

                         g[male]{Augustin Homola}
                         c[male]{Josef Homola}

                         parent{
                                g[female]{Amalie Tomanková}
                               }                              
                        } 
                  }
           }         
     }            
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{inctext}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post some compilable example code to support your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Draw a coat of arms in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79147/draw-a-coat-of-arms-in-latex)

Comment: @TeXnician I don't think it's exactly a duplicate, here the OP uses `genealogytree`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `box` option is used to give options to the underlying box processor. This can be `tcolorbox` or directly `tikz`.

For example,

```
box={bean arc,sharp corners=north,bottom=5mm},
```

reshapes the box to some coat of arms looking.

`male` and `female` are styles which can be redefined to apply male/female specific settings. If `tcolorbox` is used for processing, these styles can be set using `tcbset` as you already figured.

See the following complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\usepackage{incgraph}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf}


\begin{document}
\begin{inctext}[border=3mm]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \genealogytree[template=signpost,
      level size=2cm,
      box={bean arc,sharp corners=north,bottom=5mm},
      tcbset={
        male/.style={
          colframe=blue!50!black,
          interior style={top color=blue!20,bottom color=blue!50!yellow!5},
          drop fuzzy shadow=blue!25!black!30},
        female/.style={
          colframe=red!50!black,
          colback=red!50!yellow!5,
          interior style={top color=red!20,bottom color=red!50!yellow!5},
          drop fuzzy shadow=red!25!black!30}
      },
      ]{
    parent{
           c[female]{Silvie Polaková}
           g[male]{Alex Homola}
           parent{
                  g[male]{Radomir Palacek}
                 }
           parent{
                  c[female]{Marie Homolova}
                  g[female]{Zdenka Homolova}
                  parent{
                         g[female]{Marie Drastichova}
                        }
                  parent{
                         c[female]{Marie Homolova}

                         g[male]{Augustin Homola}
                         c[male]{Josef Homola}

                         parent{
                                g[female]{Amalie Tomanková}
                               }
                        }
                  }
           }
     }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{inctext}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So, if I  use directly tikz it will be in the form `box={ tikz={  <tikz code> }}`  into `tcbset` ? Thank you.

Comment: If `processing=tikznode` is set (as in the answer by Ignasi), options can be given directly as `box={ <tikz code> }`. Here, `<tikz code>` is anything you can set as an option for a TikZ node.

Answer (score 4):

By default `genealogytree` uses a `\tcboxfit` (from `tcolorbox`) for drawing tree leaves, but you can change it with `processing` option and select some other tool. One of them is `tikznode`. In this case, you can use whatever `node` option available to configure tree's elements.

Following code uses the `heraldic shield` shape defined in [Draw a coat of arms in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79147/draw-a-coat-of-arms-in-latex). It seems it will need some adjustment but I hope it serves as starting point.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lmodern}    
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}    
\usepackage{incgraph} 

\makeatletter    

\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  corner radius/.initial=1.5075cm,
  height shield/.initial=2.25cm,
  minimum width=3cm,
  minimum height=1.5cm,
}

\pgfdeclareshape{heraldic shield}{% taken and modified from page 631 of the manual
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] %  this is nearly a rectangle
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}

   \savedmacro\cornerradius{%
    \edef\cornerradius{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/corner radius}}%
  }

   \savedmacro\heightshield{%
    \edef\heightshield{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/height shield}}%
  }

  \savedmacro\posarc{%
    \edef\posarc{1.75cm*\heightshield}%
  }

  \backgroundpath{%  this is new
    %  store lower right in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    %  construct main path
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
     \pgfpatharc{360}{270}{\cornerradius}%
     \pgfpatharc{270}{180}{\cornerradius}%
     \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathclose
 }

  \savedanchor{\bottom}{
    \pgf@y=-\heightshield%
    \pgf@x=0cm %
    }

    \savedanchor{\arcleft}{
    \pgf@y=-\posarc%
    \pgf@x=0.9cm %
    }
    \savedanchor{\arcright}{
    \pgf@y=-\posarc%
    \pgf@x=-0.9cm %
    }
 \anchor{bottom}{\bottom}
 \anchor{arc left}{\arcleft}
 \anchor{arc right}{\arcright}
}
\makeatother

\tikzset{arms/.style={draw=#1, line width=1mm, heraldic shield, text width=20mm, align=center}}

\begin{document}
\begin{inctext}
\begin{tikzpicture}    
    \genealogytree[
    processing=tikznode,
    male/.style={box={arms=blue}},
    female/.style={box={arms=red}},
    box={arms=black}]{
    parent{           
           c[female]{Silvie Polaková} 
           g[male]{Alex Homola}  
           parent{
                  g[male]{Radomir Palacek}         
                 } 
           parent{   
                  c[female]{Marie Homolova}
                  g[female]{Zdenka Homolova}                  
                  parent{
                         g[female]{Marie Drastichova}
                        }
                  parent{
                         c[female]{Marie Homolova}

                         g[male]{Augustin Homola}
                         c[male]{Josef Homola}

                         parent{
                                g[female]{Amalie Tomanková}
                               }                              
                        } 
                  }
           }         
     }            
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{inctext}
\end{document}
```

[image]