# How to make LaTeX not "Look like Lab Notes"

Tags: fonts, sectioning, positioning, document-classes, columns

I often use LaTeX for general writings, as well as for my Lab and lecture notes. (Often, but not always via LyX).
A large portion of this is RPG homebrew.

One of my friends (who wouldn't know what LaTeX was if asked)
often comments that it looks like Lab notes.
"It looks like like my lab manual. That lab manual is a particularly good looking lab manual, but it still looks like it."
He is right.

What can I do to remove that technical writing feel?
My first attempt was to change to san serif,
but that just reminded him of a different set of notes.

---

**I'm looking for answers like:**

- "Don't use numbered headings, they always feel technical"
- "Use San Serif for Headings and Serif for body, this will invoke a more causal feeling"
- "Center Headings"
- "Use(/Don't use) columns"
- "Don't use Computer Modern, it will always invoke memories, instead use ..."
- "Use this package X" eg `wordlike` <sup>(but in this case not wordlike, I want it to look like a production book, not like a office memo)</sup>
- "Use the `memoir` DocumentClass"

---

This may seem like a open ended question, but I've tried to close it down.

It might belong on the Graphic Design SX

EDIT: Clarification (thanks to vaettchen)
I'm *not* trying to imitate the output of a word processor.
I'm trying to go for the appearance of a non-technical book, rather than feeling like something your university professor has handed you.
I want something that looks like what I might make in InDesign.
(but without the manual work of using something so WYSIWYG focused)

Comment: Use Comic Sans?

Comment: @Andrew: What kind of twisted and thoroughly black soul would suggest such a evil, evil thing? Shame on you!

Comment: Pay a kid to write it using crayons.

Comment: If you want a paper that looks like written with word processor, use one. There are enough of them for all OS.

Comment: @vaettchen: I never said anything about a word processor.
I want something that looks like what I might make in InDesign.
(but without the manual work of using something so WYSIWYG focused)

Comment: `\usepackage{wordlike}`

Comment: Less crazy than `\usepackage{wordlike}`: Just let it look like written by a [Cthulhu-worshipping madman](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29402/how-do-i-make-my-document-look-like-it-was-written-by-a-cthulhu-worshipping-madm?rq=1)

Comment: Finally, if all that does not help: Try out a couple of other document classes. See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/782/what-are-the-available-documentclass-types-and-their-uses) for a grant overview and many pointers to external refrences.

Comment: Use Paulo's document setup:

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63732/cute-document-in-latex/63759#63759

Comment: Is it LaTeX' fault if the Lab Notes are written in LaTeX? What if some TA uses Helvetica ? What would he say about that?

Comment: @percusse: I think at issue is the fact that lab notes are written quickly and without any particular attempt to add style to them, and therefore it creates a *brand*. Sure, it's not the fault of CMR that it is the current posterface for technical work, but it's also notable that the same typeface (with bold and italic variants) is used for the title, the author, the section headings, etc. (If a TA uses Helvetica, the uniformity of the Helvetica would also make the lab notes look very "note-like".) I think it's fine to ask how to go smartly about breaking the mold.

Comment: I suggest you use xkcd style plots. As shown on this page http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74878/create-xkcd-style-diagram-in-tex There are number of many other languages that can be used to generate xkcd plots and diagrams. A list of them is here http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=4731. This will make your Latex report look more fun and very cool but still retain its Latex spirit and the high quality typography that Latex is known for.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap Then it becomes a typography style question not a TeX one I'm afraid.

Comment: It is a design question for sure but I think there's merits to treating it as a TeX question too so people can make TeX-specific suggestions like saalk referring to classic-thesis below.

Comment: you already suggested it in your question -- take a look at the possibilities provided by the `memoir` class.

Comment: Many of the above comments are just mocking the question; some might be for valid fun, but this question is entirely legitimate and justified. The value of the question overrides the opinion-heaviness of any potential answers. That TeX has a characteristic look isn't only the OP's opinion. When I last checked, it seemed **Robert Bringhurst didn't discuss/recommend TeX in his book** and (this is anecdotal) **his favorite typesetting program was Adobe InDesign**. Some of the "labnote feel" undoubtedly has to do with the choice of Computer Modern and a suboptimal choice of default parameters.

Comment: **Good typesetting does not draw attention to itself.** Good documents should neither look like "this was TeX" nor like "this was definitely not TeX", simply because in the long history of printing/typesetting, most good books haven't been typeset with TeX :-) Whatever you think about the merit of the opinions that there's a "labnote feel", the opinions' existence (for some people) is problematic. Discussion (wild, vigorous, and opinionated, if necessary) on how to avoid the most "characteristic" TeX oddities and the least-liked defaults can in fact only increase the popularity of TeX.

Comment: @LoverofStructure It looks like lab notes because it's used mostly in academia. When I see Arial I immediately feel that it's typed by some company dude. But that's not Arial's problem. It is cultural. So that's an XY problem. I don't agree that the parameters are suboptimal. It's just people are tired of seeing it as default. It doesn't mean it's bad.I also don't agree that this is a valid TeX problem. It's a legitimate typesetting question though.

Comment: @percusse Word documents typeset with the defaults do have a "Word look" to them, so I think your points have validity.

Comment: I suggest you check out http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149123/21963. Absolutely elegant.

Comment: @percusse Proof of your point can be easily had by simply taking up a discipline which uses TeX very little and picking an appropriate department. Then you get asked how to produce papers which look that good even though they clearly have a TeX look. If 'LaTeX' just means 'latex' to people, your documents just look beautiful. I am sure people would not have this response if my papers really looked like lab notes. (People are less interested in the answer when you explain you cannot give them a Word template. But that's life.)

Comment: Very similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158638/make-beamer-not-look-like-beamer

But not dupliate

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a general suggestion, I'd say pick up a book of the kind you want your document to look like and go through the points you listed and the ones I mention below.

The first thing you'll want to look at is fonts: whereas Times New Roman/Arial screams "MS Office" at you, Computer Modern seems to shout "lab manual" at your friend. In plain LaTeX you can't pull in all ttf/otf fonts on your computer directly (XeTeX, ConTeXt, LuaTeX etc. can) but as ChrisS mentioned there's a list of TeX-supported fonts and you can get your usual Times/Arial if you'd like or try something more original - it really depends on your document.
The serif/sans question can be debated to death but most books use serif so if that's what you want a document to look like I'd recommend serif.
I've been using Linux Libertine successfully recently which neither looks like Times nor Computer Modern.

The next big difference most people will note (if perhaps not consciously) between your average document and TeX' defaults is the line lengths. As Knuth and the not-so-short introduction will tell you, TeX actually follows guidelines that professional typesetters have known for ages in not making lines too long and thus the whole document easier to read. 
One difficulty that you'll run into is that most non-technical books are set not just with shorter lines than "Office default" but also as a consequence printed on smaller paper sizes than letter/A4 (when did you last read a novel in A4 format?) whereas academic papers seem to come mostly with book-sized lines on document-sized paper leading to enormous amounts of white space on the pages which might be something that your friend noticed.

However, if you want to, load `fullpage` and chip away at the margins.
You could also consider increasing the line spacing or in TeX-speak `\linespread{1.3}` which will get you better readability in a long document (especially with narrow margins) and look less like your average academic paper.

`fancyhdr` will allow you to reformat your headers/footers. I don't have any design suggestions here except that if you or your friend find some document or book that definitely does not look like a lab manual you could try and emulate that.

Colour is another thing you won't find in most lab manuals. Bear in mind that while a document with rotated, rainbow-gradiented 3D-WordArt titles, headings in different font, size and colour to the body text and Comic Sans text definitely won't look like a lab manual, it will look amateurish and absolutely horrendous.

But a bit of subtle colour here and there for headings can't hurt - `sectsty` is your friend and the following pages give some examples with code:

- [title pages](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_title/0.html)
- [chapter headings](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_chapter/0.html)
- [section headings](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_section/0.html)

Changing the look of section headings will go a long way to changing the look and feel of your document. Setting them in coloured boxes or with coloured rules above/below seem to be common choices.

Whitespace between and around things is as important if not more than the font/colour/size of your headings. Make sure you don't cramp things together too closely - it may not end up looking like a lab manual but it will look bad. Again, take a book you think looks good and study the way they use white space.

Comment: "Unless you want to switch to ConTeXt or something like that you can't pull in all ttf/otf fonts on your computer directly" XeTeX and LuaTeX can both do that so you don't need to switch to ConTeXt to get ttf/otf fonts.

Comment: Also you *could* use ttf fonts directly with pdfTeX if you really wanted to. (I do.) It is just more work.

Answer (score 10):

1. **Wrapping Figures:** Use the [`wrapfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) package to float your figures to the sides of the document, rather than the top or bottom or between packages.
2. **Typefaces:** Pick typefaces [according to the document you're writing](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/03/24/how-to-choose-a-typeface/). Make sure your [typeface combinations go together](http://www.typography.com/ask-hfj/combining-fonts/). You can find typefaces in [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/), and (for XeTeX and LuaTeX) [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com).
3. **Text Treatments:** If you're going for an old-fashioned look, S P A C E D - O U T   C A P I T A L S can work for headings (with the [`soul`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/soul) package); small caps instead of bold (or even blackletter instead of bold) and [text figures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_figures) often look good.

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at the package "classic-thesis". It tries to follow the principles of Robert Bringhurst's "The Elements of Typographic Style". The results are simply beautiful.

[Official page](http://www.miede.de/index.php?page=classicthesis) and [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/)

EDIT: It even has its own LyX template.