# LaTeX class for creating markdown style output

Tags: fonts, backgrounds, markdown

I am a long time user of LaTeX. I have found, however, that
using Markdown gives me a document which is "easier on the eyes".
LaTeX often looks like textbooks.

Does anyone know LaTeX classes (or something else) which 
replicate Markdown styles such as "Github", "Github v2",
"Markdown Pro" and "Real". These titles come from the 
Markdown Pro application.

More generally, learning ways to create documents
which don't feel so "textbook"ish would be helpful 
to me.

Comment: I suppose we have to reference this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63759/1090

Comment: I would like to note that Markdown is an input format, meaning that none of the formatting is related to Markdown. The styles from the mentioned application are most probably app-specific stylesheets applied to the exported document, totally unrelated to its origin being Markdown.

Comment: So to clarify this question. You'd like to achieve an output like this: [https://github.com/szantaii/bash-weather](https://github.com/szantaii/bash-weather)?
I have a question too. Do you want to get a single page output, or multiple pages are fine?
I'll post an answer tomorrow, so please don't close this question until then.

Comment: Even changing the default font to a sans-serif

    `\usepackage[default]{opensans}`

does a lot to avoid the textbook feeling.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

So if I understood your question correctly, you want to do something like GitHub's markdown style. So I created some commands and environments to supply a GitHub-like style based on [Adam Pritchard's Markdown Cheatsheet](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet).

I used [Source Sans Pro](http://sourceforge.net/adobe/sourcesans/wiki/Home/) and [Source Code Pro](http://sourceforge.net/adobe/sourcecodepro/wiki/Home/) fonts, so you'll have to download and install them on your operating system. Here are the direct download links:

- Source Sans Pro: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourcesans.adobe/files/SourceSansPro_FontsOnly-1.050.zip/download
- Source Code Pro: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourcecodepro.adobe/files/SourceCodePro_FontsOnly-1.017.zip/download

Since I used TrueType fonts you'll have to compile the `tex` file using `xelatex`, compiling it twice to get the table of contents right.

I commented the code for easier understanding and also included examples in the document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}


% Lengths ----------------------------------------------------------------------

% save parindent to a new length, originalparindent
\newlength{\originalparindent}
\setlength{\originalparindent}{\parindent}

% set parskip to bigskipamount for space between paragraphs
\setlength{\parskip}{\bigskipamount}

% set parindent to 0pt for disabling paragraph indentation
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}


% Packages ---------------------------------------------------------------------

% geometry package for setting page
% size, and for refining page margins
\usepackage[a4paper, hscale=0.85, vscale=0.85]{geometry}

% Set font encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% url package for handlink hyperlinks
\usepackage{url}

% hyperref package for handling in-document links and styling links
\usepackage{hyperref}

% fontspec package to load custom fonts
\usepackage{fontspec}

% xcolor package for 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

% secdot package for adding dot after section numbers
\usepackage{secdot}

% ulem package for enabling strikethrough 
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

% tocloft package for disabling
% bold font in the table of contents
\usepackage{tocloft}

% titletoc package for adding a dot after
% section numbers in the table of contents
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}

% setspace package for altering linespread in tables
\usepackage{setspace}

% float package for placing tables
% and figure at exact position
\usepackage{float}

% caption package
% for caption styling 
\usepackage{caption}

% colortbl package for colored tables
\usepackage{colortbl}

% tikz package for inline code
% styling, and horizontal rules
\usepackage{tikz}

% verbatim package for verbatim
% environment in code block environments
\usepackage{verbatim}

% mdframed environment for custom
% code blocks and custom quotes
% (common options for all mdframed based
% environments are set at package loading)
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz,%
    innerleftmargin=0.5\originalparindent,%
    innerrightmargin=0.5\originalparindent,%
    skipabove=0.4\baselineskip,%
    skipbelow=0.4\baselineskip,%
    innertopmargin=0.4\baselineskip,%
    innerbottommargin=0.4\baselineskip]{mdframed}

% tabu package for
% easier tabular styling
\usepackage{tabu}


% Package Setups ---------------------------------------------------------------

% setup for hyperref package:
%   enabled pdf bookmarks,
%   setting link styles
\hypersetup{bookmarks=true,%
    bookmarksnumbered=true,%
    pdfencoding=unicode,%
    colorlinks=true,%
    pdfborder={0 0 0},%
    linkcolor=black,%
    menucolor=black,%
    citecolor=mdhyperlinkcolor,%
    urlcolor=mdhyperlinkcolor,%
    filecolor=mdhyperlinkcolor}

% setup for tikz package:
%   load library for fancy hrlues
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

% setup url package:
%   set url font to sans serif instead of teletype
\urlstyle{sf}

% Font settings ----------------------------------------------------------------

% set document default font to Source Sans Pro and its variants
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,%
    ItalicFont=Source Sans Pro Light Italic,%
    BoldFont=Source Sans Pro,%
    BoldItalicFont=Source Sans Pro Italic]{Source Sans Pro Light}

% set sans serif font to Source Sans Pro and its variants (just in case)
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text,%
    ItalicFont=Source Sans Pro Light Italic,%
    BoldFont=Source Sans Pro,%
    BoldItalicFont=Source Sans Pro Italic]{Source Sans Pro Light}

% set monospace font to Source Code Pro and its variants
\setmonofont[Mapping=tex-text,%
    ItalicFont=Source Code Pro ExtraLight,%
    BoldFont=Source Code Pro]{Source Code Pro Light}


% Color definitions ------------------------------------------------------------

\definecolor{mdfancyhlinecolor}{HTML}{CCCCCC}
\definecolor{mdsimplehlinecolor}{HTML}{DDDDDD}
\definecolor{mdhyperlinkcolor}{HTML}{4183C4}
\definecolor{mdinlinecodeboxbackgroundcolor}{HTML}{F8F8F8}
\definecolor{mdinlinecodeboxframecolor}{HTML}{DDDDDD}
\definecolor{mdblockquotelinecolor}{HTML}{DDDDDD}
\definecolor{mdalternatingtablerowcolor}{HTML}{F8F8F8}
\definecolor{mdtableframecolor}{HTML}{DDDDDD}
\definecolor{mdimgboxcolor}{HTML}{DDDDDD}


% Styling table of contents ----------------------------------------------------

% set dot fill style
\renewcommand{\cftsecdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
\renewcommand{\cftparadotsep}{\cftdotsep}
\renewcommand{\cftsubparadotsep}{\cftdotsep}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsubsecdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsubsubsecdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftparaleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftparadotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubparaleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsubparadotsep}}

% set section font style
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\normalfont}

% set indentation of toc entries
\newlength{\mycftsecindent}
\newlength{\mycftsubsecindent}
\newlength{\mycftsubsubsecindent}
\newlength{\mycftparaindent}
\newlength{\mycftsubparaindent}
\setlength{\mycftsecindent}{0.5\cftsecindent}
\setlength{\mycftsubsecindent}{0.5\cftsubsecindent}
\setlength{\mycftsubsubsecindent}{0.5\cftsubsubsecindent}
\setlength{\mycftparaindent}{0.5\cftparaindent}
\setlength{\mycftsubparaindent}{0.5\cftsubparaindent}
\setlength{\cftsecindent}{\mycftsecindent}
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{\mycftsubsecindent}
\setlength{\cftsubsubsecindent}{\mycftsubsubsecindent}
\setlength{\cftparaindent}{\mycftparaindent}
\setlength{\cftsubparaindent}{\mycftsubparaindent}
\addtolength{\cftsecnumwidth}{0.3em}
\addtolength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{0.3em}
\addtolength{\cftsubsubsecnumwidth}{0.3em}
\addtolength{\cftparanumwidth}{0.3em}
\addtolength{\cftsubparanumwidth}{0.3em}

% set parskip between toc entries
\newlength{\mycftbeforeskip}
\setlength{\mycftbeforeskip}{0.5\cftbeforesecskip}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{\mycftbeforeskip}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{\mycftbeforeskip}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsubsecskip}{\mycftbeforeskip}
\setlength{\cftbeforeparaskip}{\mycftbeforeskip}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubparaskip}{\mycftbeforeskip}

% set table of contents depth to 5
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}


% Section styling --------------------------------------------------------------

% add dots after section numbers (secdot package)
\sectiondot{section}
\sectiondot{subsection}
\sectiondot{subsubsection}
\sectiondot{paragraph}
\sectiondot{subparagraph}

% changing the style of \paragraph and \subparagraph titles, so
% text after \paragraph and \subparagraph are broken into new lines
\makeatletter
    \renewcommand\paragraph{%
        \@startsection{paragraph}{4}{0mm}%
            {-\baselineskip}%
            {.3\baselineskip}%
            {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
    \renewcommand\subparagraph{%
        \@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{0mm}%
            {-\baselineskip}%
            {.3\baselineskip}%
            {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother

% set section number up to level 5
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

% add a dot after section
% numbers in the pdf bookmarks
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150983/add-dot-to-the-end-of-section-numbering-in-pdf-bookmarks
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\Hy@numberline}[1]{#1. }
\makeatother


% Paragraph styling ------------------------------------------------------------

% prevent widows and orphans
\widowpenalty=10000
\clubpenalty=10000

% prevent overfull lines
\sloppy


% New commands -----------------------------------------------------------------

% mdtitle command for document title
% (not listend in the table of contents)
\newcommand{\mdtitle}[1]{{\LARGE\textbf{#1}}}

% mdtableofcontents command for custom styled table of contents
\newcommand{\mdtableofcontents}{{\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}\tableofcontents}}

% mdsimplehrule command for a simple horizontal rule
\newcommand{\mdsimplehrule}{%
    \nopagebreak\begin{tikzpicture}%
        \path[draw, mdsimplehlinecolor] (0, 0) -- (\textwidth{}, 0);%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

% mdfancyhrule command for a fancy horizontal rule
\newcommand{\mdfancyhrule}{%
    \nopagebreak\begin{tikzpicture}%
        \pgfdeclaredecoration{fancyhrule}{initial}{%
            \state{initial}[width=4.25pt]%
            {%
                \fill[mdfancyhlinecolor] (0pt, 0pt) -- (3pt, 3pt) -- (4.25pt, 3pt) -- (1.25pt, 0pt) -- cycle;%
            }%
            \state{final}%
            {%
                \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}%
            }%
        }%
        \path[decorate, decoration=fancyhrule] (0, 0) -- (\textwidth, 0);%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
%    \nopagebreak\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={border, angle=45, segment length=4pt, amplitude=4pt}, thick]%
%        \path[postaction={decorate, draw}, mdfancyhlinecolor] (0, 0) -- (\textwidth{}, 0);%
%    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

% mdinlinecode command for including code snippets inline
% (fake verbatim, so all special character should be escaped,
% or textmode equivalents of special characters should be used)
\newcommand{\mdinlinecode}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0ex]%
        \node[anchor=base,%
            text height=1em,%
            text depth=1ex,%
            inner ysep=0pt,%
            draw=mdinlinecodeboxframecolor,%
            fill=mdinlinecodeboxbackgroundcolor,%
            rounded corners=2pt] at (0,0) {\footnotesize\texttt{#1}};%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

% bfdescriptionlabel command for changing the description
% label style in the mdbfdescription environment
\newcommand{\bfdescriptionlabel}[1]{%
    \hspace{\labelsep}\normalfont{\textbf{#1:}}%
}

% codedescriptionlabel command for changing the description
% label style in the mdcodedescription environment
\newcommand{\codedescriptionlabel}[1]{%
    \hspace{\labelsep}\normalfont{\mdinlinecode{#1}}%
}

% mdimgbox for a frame around figures,
% but it can be used for anything
\newcommand{\mdimgbox}[1]{%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.4pt}%
    \fcolorbox{mdimgboxcolor}{white}{#1}%
}

% New environments -------------------------------------------------------------

% mdcodeblock environment for including code blocks
% (based on mdframed, breaks between pages)
\newmdenv[font=\footnotesize,%
linewidth=0.4pt,%
roundcorner=2pt,%
linecolor=mdinlinecodeboxframecolor,%
backgroundcolor=mdinlinecodeboxbackgroundcolor,%
settings={\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}}]{mdcdblk}
\newenvironment{mdcodeblock}{\endgraf\verbatim}{\endverbatim}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{mdcodeblock}{\begin{mdcdblk}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{mdcodeblock}{\end{mdcdblk}}

% mdnonbreakcodeblock environment for including code blocks
% (based on mdframed, doesn't break between pages)
\newmdenv[font=\footnotesize,%
linewidth=0.4pt,%
roundcorner=2pt,%
linecolor=mdinlinecodeboxframecolor,%
backgroundcolor=mdinlinecodeboxbackgroundcolor,%
nobreak=true,%
settings={\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}}]{mdnonbreakcdblk}
\newenvironment{mdnonbreakcodeblock}{\endgraf\verbatim}{\endverbatim}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{mdnonbreakcodeblock}{\begin{mdnonbreakcdblk}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{mdnonbreakcodeblock}{\end{mdnonbreakcdblk}}

% mdblockquote environment for custom styled blockquotes
% (based on mdframed, breaks between pages)
\newmdenv[linewidth=3pt,%
linecolor=mdblockquotelinecolor,%
topline=false,%
rightline=false,%
bottomline=false,%
settings={\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}}]{mdblockquote}

% mditemize environment for
% custom styled unordered lists
\newenvironment{mditemize}%
    {\begin{itemize}
        \setlength{\parskip}{0.5\smallskipamount}}%
    {\end{itemize}}

% mdenumerate environment for
% custom styled enumerated lists
\newenvironment{mdenumerate}%
    {\begin{enumerate}
        \setlength{\parskip}{0.5\smallskipamount}}%
    {\end{enumerate}}

% mdbfdescription environment for
% custom (bold) styled description lists
\newenvironment{mdbfdescription}%
{\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}{\bfdescriptionlabel}%
    \begin{description}%
    \setlength{\itemindent}{\parindent}%
    \setlength{\parskip}{0.5\smallskipamount}}%
{\end{description}}

% mdcodedescription environment for
% custom (mdinlinecode) styled description lists
\newenvironment{mdcodedescription}%
{\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}{\codedescriptionlabel}
    \begin{description}%
    \setlength{\itemindent}{\parindent}%
    \setlength{\parskip}{0.5\smallskipamount}}%
{\end{description}}


% Document start ---------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\mdtitle{GitHub Markdown style \LaTeX}

\mdfancyhrule

\mdtableofcontents

\mdfancyhrule

\section{Headings}

Document title with \mdinlinecode{\textbackslash{}mdtitle\{\}}.

Standard \LaTeX section headings can be used (level 1--5).

\subsection{Subsection}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

\paragraph{Paragraph}

\subparagraph{Subparagraph}

And these also appear nicely in the table of contents.

\mdsimplehrule

\section{Emphasis}

Emphasis, aka \emph{italics}, with standard \mdinlinecode{\textbackslash{}emph\{\}}.

Strong emphasis, aka \textbf{bold}, with standard \mdinlinecode{\textbackslash{}textbf\{\}}.

\emph{\textbf{Combined emphasis}} with standard \mdinlinecode{\textbackslash{}emph\{\}} and \mdinlinecode{\textbackslash{}textbf\{\}}.

\sout{Strikethrough} with \mdinlinecode{\textbackslash{}sout\{\}} from the \mdinlinecode{ulem} package.

\mdsimplehrule

\section{Lists}

Unordered list with the \mdinlinecode{mditemize} environment:

\begin{mditemize}
\item foo
\item bar
\end{mditemize}

Enumeration, aka ordered list with the \mdinlinecode{mdenumerate} environment:

\begin{mdenumerate}
\item foo
\item bar
\end{mdenumerate}

Bold style description list with the \mdinlinecode{mdbfdescription} environment:

\begin{mdbfdescription}
\item[foo] bar
\item[R. Daneel Olivaw] A fictional robot created by Isaac Asimov.
\end{mdbfdescription}

Inline code description list with the \mdinlinecode{mdcodedescription} environment

\begin{mdcodedescription}
\item[void *] A special type of pointer that can be pointed at objects of any data type.
\item[R. Daneel Olivaw] a fictional robot created by Isaac Asimov.
\end{mdcodedescription}

\emph{Note: the description label inside the \mdinlinecode{mdcodedescription} environment is fake verbatim, so everything must be escaped inside it or textmode equivalents should be used of special characters. (See \hyperref[sec:mdinlinecodedef]{\mdinlinecode{\textbackslash{}mdinlinecode\{\}}'s definition}.)}

\newpage

Combined lists are also available. The style modifications don't affect nesting:

\begin{mdenumerate}
\item This supposed to be an example with custom styled lists.
\begin{mditemize}
\item unordered
\item list
\end{mditemize}
\item Let's see a nested description list.
\begin{mdbfdescription}
\item[The Doctor] So, the year 5 billion. The Sun expands, the Earth gets roasted.
\item[Rose] That was our first date.
\end{mdbfdescription}
\end{mdenumerate}

\mdsimplehrule

\section{Links}

Links with description with \mdinlinecode{\textbackslash{}href\{url\}\{description\}}:

\href{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Laws_of_Robotics}{Three Laws of Robotics - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia}

URLs with \mdinlinecode{\textbackslash{}url\{\}}:

\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Laws_of_Robotics}

\mdsimplehrule

\section{Inline code and code blocks}

Inline code with \mdinlinecode{\textbackslash{}mdinlinecode\{inline code\}}:

Lorem ipsum dolor \mdinlinecode{sit} amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis auctor \mdinlinecode{nunc}. Nam ac egestas lectus, ac tincidunt purus. Aliquam viverra dictum est, ut pretium magna tristique eget. Donec venenatis \mdinlinecode{purus} \mdinlinecode{eget} justo malesuada suscipit.

\emph{Note: \mdinlinecode{\textbackslash{}mdinlinecode\{\}} is fake verbatim, so everything must be escaped inside it or textmode equivalents should be used of special characters.}

Code blocks with the \mdinlinecode{mdcodeblock} environment (the example shows \mdinlinecode{\textbackslash{}mdinlinecode\{\}}'s definition):

\label{sec:mdinlinecodedef}

\begin{mdcodeblock}
\newcommand{\mdinlinecode}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0ex]%
        \node[anchor=base,%
            text height=1em,%
            text depth=1ex,%
            inner ysep=0pt,%
            draw=mdinlinecodeboxframecolor,%
            fill=mdinlinecodeboxbackgroundcolor,%
            rounded corners=2pt] at (0,0) {\footnotesize\texttt{#1}};%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{mdcodeblock}

Or with the \mdinlinecode{mdnonbreakcodeblock} environment, which won't break between pages.

\mdsimplehrule

\section{Figures}
A framed figure (\mdinlinecode{\textbackslash{}mdimgbox\{\}}) with left aligned caption:

\begin{mdcodeblock}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \captionsetup{justification=justified, singlelinecheck=false}
    \mdimgbox{\textcolor{white!0}{\rule{0.333\textwidth}{0.333\textwidth}}}
    \caption{\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deus_Irae}}
\end{figure}
\end{mdcodeblock}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \captionsetup{justification=justified, singlelinecheck=false}
    \mdimgbox{\textcolor{white!0}{\rule{0.333\textwidth}{0.333\textwidth}}}
    \caption{\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deus_Irae}}
\end{figure}

\mdsimplehrule

\section{Tables}

Table created with the help of \mdinlinecode{colortbl} and the standard table environments:

\begin{mdcodeblock}
{\linespread{1.9}
\begin{table}[H]
    \rowcolors{2}{mdalternatingtablerowcolor}{white}
    \begin{tabular}{!{\color{mdtableframecolor}\vrule}l!%
{\color{mdtableframecolor}\vrule}l!{\color{mdtableframecolor}\vrule}}
        \arrayrulecolor{mdtableframecolor}\hline
        \textbf{Distribution} & \textbf{Package name}\\
        \arrayrulecolor{mdtableframecolor}\hline
        Arch Linux & \mdinlinecode{ncurses}\\
        Debian & \mdinlinecode{ncurses-bin}\\
        Fedora & \mdinlinecode{ncurses}\\
        openSUSE & \mdinlinecode{ncurses-utils}\\
        Ubuntu & \mdinlinecode{ncurses-bin}\\
        \arrayrulecolor{mdtableframecolor}\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}}
\end{mdcodeblock}

{\linespread{1.9}
\begin{table}[H]
    \rowcolors{2}{mdalternatingtablerowcolor}{white}
    \begin{tabular}{!{\color{mdtableframecolor}\vrule}l!%
{\color{mdtableframecolor}\vrule}l!{\color{mdtableframecolor}\vrule}}
        \arrayrulecolor{mdtableframecolor}\hline
        \textbf{Distribution} & \textbf{Package name}\\
        \arrayrulecolor{mdtableframecolor}\hline
        Arch Linux & \mdinlinecode{ncurses}\\
        Debian & \mdinlinecode{ncurses-bin}\\
        Fedora & \mdinlinecode{ncurses}\\
        openSUSE & \mdinlinecode{ncurses-utils}\\
        Ubuntu & \mdinlinecode{ncurses-bin}\\
        \arrayrulecolor{mdtableframecolor}\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}}

Table created using only \mdinlinecode{tabu}:

\begin{mdcodeblock}
\taburowcolors[2] {white .. mdalternatingtablerowcolor}
\taburulecolor{mdtableframecolor}
\tabulinesep=^1.2ex
\tabulinesep=_0.75ex
\arrayrulewidth=0.4pt
\everyrow{\hline}
\begin{tabu}{|l|l|}
\rowfont[c]\bfseries
Distribution & Package name\\
Arch Linux & \mdinlinecode{ncurses}\\
Debian & \mdinlinecode{ncurses-bin}\\
Fedora & \mdinlinecode{ncurses}\\
openSUSE & \mdinlinecode{ncurses-utils}\\
Ubuntu & \mdinlinecode{ncurses-bin}\\
\end{tabu}
\end{mdcodeblock}

\taburowcolors[2] {white .. mdalternatingtablerowcolor}
\taburulecolor{mdtableframecolor}
\tabulinesep=^1.2ex
\tabulinesep=_0.75ex
\arrayrulewidth=0.4pt
\everyrow{\hline}
\begin{tabu}{|l|l|}
\rowfont[c]\bfseries
Distribution & Package name\\
Arch Linux & \mdinlinecode{ncurses}\\
Debian & \mdinlinecode{ncurses-bin}\\
Fedora & \mdinlinecode{ncurses}\\
openSUSE & \mdinlinecode{ncurses-utils}\\
Ubuntu & \mdinlinecode{ncurses-bin}\\
\end{tabu}

\newpage

Also created with \mdinlinecode{tabu}:

\begin{mdcodeblock}
\begin{table}[H]
\captionsetup{justification=justified, singlelinecheck=false}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering}m{#1}}
\taburowcolors[2] {white .. mdalternatingtablerowcolor}
\taburulecolor{mdtableframecolor}
\tabulinesep=^1.2ex
\tabulinesep=_0.75ex
\arrayrulewidth=0.4pt
\everyrow{\hline}
\begin{tabu}{|l|C{2.5cm}|C{2.5cm}|p{5.5cm}|}
\rowfont[c]\bfseries
Day & Minimum Temperature & Maximum Temperature & Summary \\
Monday & 11 \textdegree{}C & 22 \textdegree{}C & A clear day with lots
of sunshine. However, the strong breeze will bring down the temperatures. \\
Tuesday & ~9 \textdegree{}C & 19 \textdegree{}C & Cloudy with rain,
across many northern regions. Clear spells across most of Scotland and
Northern Ireland, but rain reaching the far northwest. \\
Wednesday & 10 \textdegree{}C & 21 \textdegree{}C & Rain will still linger
for the morning. Conditions will improve by early afternoon
and continue throughout the evening. \\
\end{tabu}
\caption{Weather forecast for the next 3 days.}
\end{table}
\end{mdcodeblock}

\begin{table}[H]
\captionsetup{justification=justified, singlelinecheck=false}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering}m{#1}}
\taburowcolors[2] {white .. mdalternatingtablerowcolor}
\taburulecolor{mdtableframecolor}
\tabulinesep=^1.2ex
\tabulinesep=_0.75ex
\arrayrulewidth=0.4pt
\everyrow{\hline}
\begin{tabu}{|l|C{2.5cm}|C{2.5cm}|p{5.5cm}|}
\rowfont[c]\bfseries
Day & Minimum Temperature & Maximum Temperature & Summary \\
Monday & 11 \textdegree{}C & 22 \textdegree{}C & A clear day with lots
of sunshine. However, the strong breeze will bring down the temperatures. \\
Tuesday & ~9 \textdegree{}C & 19 \textdegree{}C & Cloudy with rain,
across many northern regions. Clear spells across most of Scotland and
Northern Ireland, but rain reaching the far northwest. \\
Wednesday & 10 \textdegree{}C & 21 \textdegree{}C & Rain will still linger
for the morning. Conditions will improve by early afternoon
and continue throughout the evening. \\
\end{tabu}
\caption{Weather forecast for the next 3 days.}
\end{table}

Text source: \url{http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Text_wrapping_in_tables}

\mdsimplehrule

\section{Blockquotes}

Blockquotes with the \mdinlinecode{mdblockquote} environment:

\begin{mdblockquote}
The Three Laws of Robotics (often shortened to The Three Laws or Three Laws) are a set of rules devised by the science fiction author Isaac Asimov.

The rules were introduced in his 1942 short story ``Runaround'', although they had been foreshadowed in a few earlier stories. The Three Laws are:

\begin{mdenumerate}
\item A robot may not injure a human being or, through inaction, allow a human being to come to harm.
\item A robot must obey the orders given to it by human beings, except where such orders would conflict with the First Law.
\item A robot must protect its own existence as long as such protection does not conflict with the First or Second Law.
\end{mdenumerate}
\end{mdblockquote}

Source: \href{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Laws_of_Robotics}{Three Laws of Robotics -- Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia}

\mdsimplehrule

\section{Horizontal rules}

Fancy horizontal rule with \mdinlinecode{\textbackslash{}mdfancyhrule}:

\mdfancyhrule

Simple horizontal rule with \mdinlinecode{\textbackslash{}mdsimplehrule}:

\mdsimplehrule

\section{etc.}

Table of contents with \mdinlinecode{\textbackslash{}mdtableofcontents}.

List of figures and tables are the same as usual (\mdinlinecode{\textbackslash{}listoffigures}, \mdinlinecode{\textbackslash{}listoftables}).

\mdsimplehrule

\end{document}
```

Click on the image to view it in large size.

[image: example]

*Note that I've heavily edited the original answer. I fixed some issues, added new commands, and environments, and rewritten a few things. For the changes I made, see the [edit history of this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/149123/revisions).*

Comment: You can also `\usepackage{sourcesanspro, sourcecodepro}`.

Comment: Brilliant! Are we looking at a class, maybe?

Comment: @Holene I'm working on a more mature version of my answer, however I've never written any classes. I don't know if I'll have time to maintain a class in the future. I'd rather choose to include the preamble in a separate tex file for now.

Comment: AFAIK `fontenc` and `fontspec` in the same document is wrong.

Comment: I would second the call for a class.

Comment: Beautiful. I wonder what if one only wants the inline code and the code blocks.

Answer (score 2):

My [latex-to-internet](https://github.com/loopspace/latex-to-internet) class can produce Markdown output.

As Markdown is more limited than LaTeX, my advice is to write the document knowing in advance that it is going to be converted to Markdown otherwise formatting information will be lost.