# How to implement book style notes/usage fields?

Tags: quoting, notes

I would like to implement Note style fields like in here (excerpt from https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/environment.html#manifest for demonstration)

[image]

How can I do this in LaTeX ?

P.S. Please change the tags if I have chosen the wrong ones.

**EDIT**

I have came up with something more or less like this:

```
\vspace{1em}\hspace{1.5em}
\hbox{%
\vrule\hspace{.5em}\parbox{.9\textwidth}%
{
\textbf{Note:}
Text.....
}
}
\vspace{1em}
```

Which produces:

[image]

But I am having problems to define an environment with this.

Comment: You can define new environments like described here, maybe this can give you a start: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros#New_Environments

Comment: Something similar is in this [anwer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149123/21930) (see `mdblockquote`).

Answer (score 6):

What about something more similar to the one you are trying to copy, made with `mdframed`?

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\newmdenv[%
    rightmargin = -10pt,
    skipabove = 1.2\topskip,
    rightline = false,
    topline = false,
    bottomline = false,
    innertopmargin = 2pt,
    innerbottommargin = 2pt,
    linewidth = 2pt,
    linecolor = cyan
]{leftlined}

\newenvironment{note}
  {\leftlined\textbf{Note:}}
  {\endleftlined}

\begin{document}

\noindent\lipsum[1]

\begin{note}
\lipsum[2]
\end{note}

\noindent\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

I've first defined a new `mdframed` environment called `leftlined` and then I've used it to define a new environment `note` that adds the text "Note:" at its beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally defined environment for this :

```
\newenvironment{note}[1]
  {
  \vspace{1em}\hspace{1.5em}
  \hbox{%
  \vrule\hspace{.5em}\parbox{.9\textwidth}%
  {
  \textbf{Note:}
  #1
  }}}
  {\vspace{1em}}
```

To be used as follows:

```
\begin{note}
{"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui
officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."}
\end{note}
```

Which would produce: 
[image]

Comment: It is probably fine but not "breakable" at a break page. A solution with `mdframed` is better in this regard.