# Interactive Mathematics quiz competition for MSc students

Tags: beamer, presentations

I need to conduct a quiz for MSc level students. It is an intercollegiate competition. I have prepared the questions in Algebra and Analysis for six rounds. Now comes the LaTeX part.

I have used `beamer` to create the questions in one side and the answer in the next slide. It works perfectly. But I want it to be more lively and interactive.

I am wondering about the following things.

1. Is it possible to maintain the dynamic scores of each team in all the slides?
2. If the answer is correct I want to play a video and if the answer is wrong I want to play another video to make the event to be fun. How to do this?
3. What are some other interesting features of LaTeX that I can use to make the quiz more lively?

Kindly share your thought.

Comment: LaTeX is not really suitable for interactive presentations like this. A more practical solution could be to build a web browser-based presentation using MathJax for typesetting the mathematics.

Comment: Thank you. But I am not familiar with MathJax. I will check nevertheless. Can you please tell me about my third question.

Comment: You can add some animations or try to make the design and layout of the slides more dynamic, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158638/make-beamer-not-look-like-beamer and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105621/beautiful-presentations-done-with-tex-and-related-systems for some examples.

Comment: I think you need to check the package of eqexam.

Comment: Any updates on your demand ? Do you still have a request ?

Comment: @BambOo I did the quiz the way I explained in the question. If you have some better idea please share. Thank you.

Comment: Yes. If you have some updates please share it with me. Thank you.