# How to create a Book Cover with pdfpages

Tags: pdfpages

i know there are many questions on how to create a book cover, but my questions seems to be a bit different.

I create a frontpage, a backpage and the spine for my cover

Frontpage:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  a5paper
}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

{\Large Front}
\vspace*{4cm}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Backpage:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  a5paper
}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

{\Large Back}
\vspace*{4cm}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Spine:

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}
%
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[rotate=90] (a1) at (0,0){Lorem ipsum};
\node[rotate=90] (a1) at (-0.2,10){Etiam lobortis facilisis sem.};
\node[rotate=90] (a1) at (0.2,10){Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And putting all together in the cover:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{papersize={307mm,210mm}} 
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdfmerge[nup=3x1]{back,spine,front}
\end{document}
```

The front and back pages are Din A5, so the cover has the papersice Din A4, which is 297 mm x 210, so i added 10 mm for the spine, which results in 307 mm.

Unfortunately there is to much whitespace added, i played around with some options of includepdfmerge, but i didn't get it work.

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for the white space added with `\includepdfmerge[nup=3x1]{back,spine,front}` can be understood reading next paragraph from `pdfpages` documentation:

[image]

As can be seen, although `spine` has different size from front and back covers, `pdfpages` uses `back.pdf` size as template and `spine.pdf` is centered inside a A5 rectangle.

With next `cover.tex`

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{BackPage}\includegraphics{Spine}\includegraphics{FrontPage}
\end{document}
```

the result is

[image]

**2nd version**

The first version didn't considered the real size of `spine`. Next `spine.tex` produces a 10mm x 210mm spine.pdf with its contains centered which can be easily aligned with Front and Back covers.

Spine.tex:

```
\documentclass[border=0pt,tikz]{standalone}
%
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[rotate=90] (a1) at (0,0){Lorem ipsum};
\node[rotate=90] (a2) at (-0.2,10){Etiam lobortis facilisis sem.};
\node[rotate=90] (a3) at (0.2,10){Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.};

\node[fit=(a1) (a2) (a3), anchor=center, minimum width=10mm, 
      minimum height=21cm, inner sep=0pt] (spine) {};

%\draw (spine.south west) rectangle ++(1,21);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The cover looks like:

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't Front and Back positions be exchanged? ;)

Comment: Or just switched?

Comment: Thank you very much! One little point, i wanted the format 307 mm x 210 mm (the spine should be 10 mm), with this soulution the format results in 305 mm x 210 mm. But i would be reasonable to create the spine with 10 mm.

Comment: Is it further possible to vertically center the spine?

Comment: @user2143654 I've updated the answer. Is it correct now?

Answer (score 10):

Some days ago a new package was added to CTAN: [bookcover](http://ctan.org/pkg/bookcover). With this name you can image its main goal, producing bookcovers and dustcovers. You can watch two layout examples in [What are the available “documentclass” types and their uses?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231971/1952).

Using this package it's not necessary to edit, front, back and spine parts and join them with `pdfpages`, everything can be declared and composed into a unique text file.

Next code shows how to produce a book cover with more or less like OP wanted. I couldn't resit to use [Paulo's duck](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63759/1952)

```
\documentclass[marklength=0mm,
    coverwidth=148.5mm,
    coverheight=210mm,
    bleedwidth=0mm,
    spinewidth=10mm]{bookcover}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{duck}

\begin{document}

%back cover
\setbookcover{bgcolor}{back}{%
color=yellow!20,
}

\setbookcover{fgsecond}{back}{%
\vspace{2.5cm}
\centering
\scalebox{3.5}{\drawflower}
\vfill
}

\setbookcover{fgfirst}{back}{%
\centering
\begin{minipage}[c]{.7\textwidth}
{
\vspace*{4cm}
\Large Back}
\vspace*{4cm}

\blindtext
\end{minipage}
}

%front cover
\setbookcover{bgcolor}{front}{%
color=yellow!20,
}

\setbookcover{fgsecond}{front}{%
\vspace{3cm}
\centering
\scalebox{3.5}{\drawduck}
\vfill
}

\setbookcover{fgfirst}{front}{%
\centering
\begin{minipage}[c]{.7\textwidth}
{
\vspace*{4cm}
\Large Front}
\vspace*{4cm}

\blindtext
\end{minipage}
}

%spine
\setbookcover{bgcolor}{spine}{%
color=yellow!50,
}

\setbookcover{fgfirst}{spine}{
\vfill
\centering
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Lorem ipsum\hspace{5cm}
\begin{tabular}{c}
Etiam lobortis facilisis sem.\\
Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.
\end{tabular}}
\vfill}

\makebookcover
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can draw every thing in one tikz picture.

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,calc}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[minimum height=210mm,minimum width=148.5mm,outer sep=0pt] (a)
{};
\node[anchor=north west,text width=98.5mm,align=justify] at ($(a.north west) +(25mm,-25mm)$){\kant[1]};
\node[anchor=north west,rotate=90,minimum height=10mm,outer sep=0pt,inner xsep=5mm] (a1) at (a.south east){Lorem ipsum};
\node[anchor=north east,rotate=90,minimum height=10mm,outer sep=0pt,align=center,inner xsep=5mm] (a2) at (a.north east){Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. \\Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.};
\node[minimum height=210mm,minimum width=148.5mm,outer sep=0pt,anchor=north west] (b) at (a2.south east)
{};
\node[anchor=north west,text width=98.5mm,align=justify] at ($(b.north west) +(25mm,-25mm)$){\kant[1]};

%% following is for just demo
\draw (a.south east) rectangle (b.north west);
\draw[red] (a.south east) rectangle +(10mm,210mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For spine, adjust `inner xsep` suitably. Last two lines of code are just for demo to visualize the width of spine. Remove them.

Comment: Thank you very much, this looks really good. For me the first answer is better because i have a front and back pdf page which i want put together in one cover. The lorem ipsum test is just an example for this.