# How can I design book cover pages?

Tags: graphics, rotating, books, covers

How can I design the following cover with `\latex` in A4 paper, landspace?

[image]

Related to: http://tug.org/pracjourn/2007-1/robbers/robbers.pdf

Comment: Is it a single 'page' that you'd print? Have you considered using the following packages: `geometry` (page dimensions); `graphicx` (include graphics), `adjustbox` or `tcolorbox` (to put text in boxes)?

Comment: Yes, it is a single page and landspace A4. @jon.

Comment: And what have you tried to do? Do you know how to include graphics? Do you know how to set page dimensions?

Comment: I tried. Only I don't added rotate text (1 cm), and left PNG. I know include graphics, and a little set page dimensions.

Comment: Ah, great. Well please post the code you have already. You can use the `mwe` package to include some 'dummy' images for the purposes of the question.  (One reason to post the non-working code is that it politely saves people work who are trying [or willing] to help you.)

Comment: You can use geometry to create a single page the right size, and tikz nodes to lay out both text and graphics.

Comment: `148*2+10=306>A4` How is this supposed to work?

Comment: Package `dustcover`.

Comment: @Johannes_B oversize might be used for blurbs?

Comment: Package [`bookcover`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bookcover) and an [example](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/232723/1952)

Comment: Approaches to position things absolutely on a page may be helpful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808/what-are-the-ways-to-position-things-absolutely-on-the-page