# Book template for middle school math

Tags: templates, books

Writing a book for middle schoolers requires different formatting than for older students. 
Many books are written for this audience, and many LaTeX book templates are available too, yet I cannot find good templates for middle school math book.

I know LaTeX is very powerful and could be used to create such a template, but it also would be very time consuming, so if one exists already....

Here is a [link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/2c32f038a0229609b0f016972ae6386220190219001037/3597b38e4aa79545130faa6db7a6403c20190219001037/6ca345) to an excerpt of a book for 7th graders.

Based on a few comments from marmot, I will expand with some pictures so that the question is "self-contained"

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can certainly recreate all these things with titlesec and tikz. Whether or not there is a template that does that, I don't know.

Comment: almost all the shown examples are possible, but not sure any defined template available, you need to create, hope so...

Comment: See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63732/cute-child-friendly-document-in-latex for an example

Comment: I love this Layout. Can you send me a link to the excerpt of the book?

Comment: Book template for middle school math ,How do I get this LaTeX template?