# Using ConTeXts cow font with pdfTeX

Tags: fonts, pdftex, fun

So I have really become intrigued with the [Cow font of context](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb27-1/tb86hoekwater-cows.pdf), however I really wish I would be able to use this with latex. I found a place, where it listed the steps on what to do, but it was rather vague on how one would actually do these steps. The steps where:

> it "just" requires that you grab the stuff in cont-tmf.zip and put it
>   in a texmf-local sort of tree, texhash, and then updmap-sys --Enable
>   Map koeieletters.map ([link](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2009-06/msg00919.html))

Can anybody explain to me what I actually need to do to get this installed, such that I can use it with latex? I have located the con-tmf.zip file on my computer.

Comment: could you be more precise about the engine you want to use the fonts with? Your tags have ›context‹; the question you're referring to pertains to ›pdflatex‹; and your title has ›latex‹. I'm assuming it's good old pdflatex, but in that case I'd re-tag the question.

Comment: It's for use with pdflatex :)

Comment: Out of interest could anyone using this font get the logo ligatures to work ?  For instance from the "Cow font of Context" link above, there is a section describing that "TeX", "MP" and "ConTeXt" have predefined ligatures and should render differently, I was wondering if anyone got this to work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I installed them by running

```
tlmgr install cowfont --repository http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/2012
```

...which gave me:

```
tlmgr: package repository http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/2012
[1/1, ??:??/??:??] install: cowfont [656k]
tlmgr: package log updated at d:/programs/texlive/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
running mktexlsr ...
done running mktexlsr.
running updmap-sys ...

updmap-sys failed (status 1), output:
updmap is using the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  d:/programs/texlive/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
  d:/programs/texlive/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  d:/programs/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap is using the following updmap.cfg file for writing changes:
  d:/programs/texlive/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
dvips output dir: "d:/programs/texlive/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap"
pdftex output dir: "d:/programs/texlive/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap"
dvipdfmx output dir: "d:/programs/texlive/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap"
pxdvi output dir: "d:/programs/texlive/texmf-var/fonts/map/pxdvi/updmap"

ERROR:  The following map file(s) couldn't be found:
        koeieletters.map (in d:/programs/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)

        Did you run mktexlsr?

        You can disable non-existent map entries using the option
          --syncwithtrees.
```

so that package doesn't seem to include the .map file, so I got it from [here](http://source.contextgarden.net/fonts/map/pdftex/context/koeieletters.map) and after another `texhash`, re-ran the part that had failed:

```
updmap-sys --Enable Map koeieletters.map
```

**update:**
As the package doesn't contain any .sty or .fd files [(yet),](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115471/using-contexts-cow-font-with-latex/115507?noredirect=1#comment255725_115507) we have to do the necessary definitions ourselves:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{CowFont}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{CowFont}{m}{n}{<-> koeieletters}{}

\begin{document}
\usefont{T1}{CowFont}{m}{n}
stop stealing sheep
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the family is defined by a .fd file, which in your case you have not got.  shall i submit my little koeie.sty and koeie.fd to ctan?

Comment: that's right, there's no fd files in that package either. I don't think I'll become a passionate cowfont user, but I'm sure some people will appreciate your .sty and .fd files...

Comment: The [cowsay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cowsay) macro `\newcommand{\cowsay}[1]{{\usefont{T1}{CowFont}{m}{n} #1}}` is rather usefull.

Answer (score 5):

I tried [Nils solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115507/6563) with an TeXLive 2015 installation and I failed:

```
tlmgr.pl: The TeX Live versions supported by the repository
http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/2012
  (2011--2012)
do not include the version of the local installation
  (2015).
```

I found no actual repository with cowfont, but I found [another solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213112/how-to-create-a-a-package-that-can-be-installed-by-tlmgr):

1. Download the source from http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/2012/archive/cowfont.tar.xz
2. Call `tlmgr install --file cowfont.tar.xz` in the directory of the download.
3. That's it, you can use the font.
4. Repeat the same procedure with http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/2012/archive/cowfont.doc.tar.xz

Answer (score 1):

With Miktex 2.9 it is also possible to install the font. I managed to do so following the above instructions and using those in the [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/88424/edit) provided by @knut. If you are not the admin user on your system remove the `--admin` switches as necessary while following the instructions.

1. Download and extract the [`cowfont.tar.xz`](https://texlive.texjp.org/2019/tlcontrib/archive/cowfont.tar.xz) archive (The URL from @knut's answer is now invalid) into `EXTRACTED\`.
2. Remove the tlpkg folder it is not necessary.
3. The subfolders named `context` should be renamed into the subfolders `hoekwater\koeieletters`. (I'm not sure this is entirely necessary)
4. Now you should have a texmf compliant tree which you can copy into the miktex tree, copy `EXTRACTED\fonts` to `miktex\root\` (For a default installation `C:\program files\miktex2.9\`)
5. Then run `initexmf --admin --edit-config-file updmap` and add the following lines. The file name comes from the file `EXTRACTED\fonts\map\pdftex\hoekwater\koeieletters\*.map`. Once edited save the file, I did not have to change the default save location.

   ```
   # koeieletters
   Map koeieletters-2013.map
   ```
6. Then run `initexmf --admin -u` followed by `updmap` and refresh your fndb as usual.

There are also these [instructions](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2009-06/msg00919.html) which one has not yet tried.

**Note** : This post is a community wiki, please edit it as necessary.