# How to create a a package that can be installed by tlmgr?

Tags: texlive, installing, package-writing

I want to be able to use a proprietary font on a number of Linux machines for which TeXLive is installed locally (not through the package manager). I have followed [How do I use TrueType Fonts with PDFTeX using otftotfm?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52819/how-do-i-use-truetype-fonts-with-pdftex-using-otftotfm) and have my proprietary font working with `pdflatex` when all the files (map, encoding, tfm, pfb, ...) are in the working directory. I then followed [Manual font installation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/manual-font-installation) and can manually install the font. I would like to automate the final step. Normally, I would create a Linux package that would install the needed files and do the configuration steps. Since I have TeXLive installed locally, I don't feel like using the system package manager is the way to go. I would like to create a TeXLive package and use `tlmgr` to manage it.

The end goal is I want people to be able to do `tlmgr --file myfont` and then be able to use the font. Is this possible?

Comment: If you are using Debian, why not to make a deb file?

Comment: @Sigur Had I installed TeXLive with the system package manager, I could just create a `deb` file. Since I went with a local install of TeXLive, which means TeXlive is installed in `/usr/local`, it is bad form for a `deb` package to install or modify anything in `/usr/local`.

Comment: You can use the local folder to do that. Here I have `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/` or you can use `~/texmf-local`.

Comment: @Sigur I am pretty sure fonts are not the same as packages and classes in that you need to run `updmap` after adding things to `texmf-local`.

Comment: Well, I installed a font there. I have the folders `bibtex  doc  dvips  fonts  ls-R  metapost  tex  tlpkg  web2c` and everything works well. You can ask deb to execute it.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to create a TeX Live package, you need to do the following steps. I assume here that you are *not* shipping any binaries, but only files in a the texmf hierarchy. Also assume that the package is called `foo`:

- prepare a TDS tree of the package, say in `foo`, that is, you have `foo/tex`, `foo/fonts` etc.
- write a tlpobj file in `foo/tlpkg/tlpobj/foo.tlpobj` that contains the following lines:

```
name foo
category Package
revision 1
shortdesc something reasonable about your package
relocated 1
execute addMap foo.map
longdesc some more description
longdesc if you want to add it
longdesc can be multi line
runfiles size=1
 RELOC/fonts/map/dvips/foobar.map
 RELOC/fonts/truetype/....
 ...
docfiles size=1
 RELOC/doc/fonts/foo/README
 ....
srcfiles size=1
 RELOCE/source/fonts/foo/...
```

where the following things are important:

- `relocated 1`
- the `size` parameter can be the actual size in 1k multiplies, but you don't need to add the correct number
- list *all* files in one of the section!
- if you have a map file included and want to activate it, add the `execute` line, possible adjusting the name of the file

After that go into `foo` and do `tar -cJvf foo.tar.xz .` to get the package, which you can install with `tlmgr install --from-file foo.tar.xz`.

Examples for how a tlpobj file looks like can be found by looking at the `texlive.tlpdb`, each stanza starting with `name` is one.

Comment: Can this be used to install into the local tree?

Comment: If you use user mode tlmgr, then it can be installed into an arbitrary texmf tree.

Comment: `tlmgr install --from-file foo.tar.xz` fails `with Unknown option: from-file` while `tlmgr install --file foo.tar.xz` fails with: `Use of uninitialized value $_[0] in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/local/texlive/2014/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm line 74.` `Use of uninitialized value $_[0] in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/local/texlive/2014/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm line 74. Cannot open tlpobj file:  at /usr/local/texlive/2014/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm line 74.`

Comment: @StrongBad sorry for the late answer - it should have been `--file` ...

Comment: @norbert as I mentioned in the previous comment, I tried with the `--file` and get an error.

Comment: I don't see a comment related to this. You mentioned that `--from-file` does not work, which is true. You need to use `--file` ... am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I was blind ... can you put the actual .tar.xz somewhere onto a web location so that I can try it out and check the contents? Thanks

Comment: @norbert --file is correct, but this does not install dependencies when specified. is there a trick to do that? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/663447/tlmgr-install-package-with-dependencies

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. No, installation from file cannot trigger installation of dependencies as of now.