# Connecting 3 nodes on forme triangle with TiKz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

It is possible to draw this triangle with TiKz?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Yes, this should be possible ....

Comment: Well, this is `do it for me question`, actually. I am no TikZ expert, but I think this can be done step by step reading the `pgfmanual`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It's usually nice to provide at least a starting code so answerers don't need to start from scratch. If you know how to typeset the nodes (the rectangles), then please provide at least that. :)

Comment: This is more or less what `smartdiagram` does by default.  All you need is `\usepackage{smartdiagram}` in the preamble and then `\smartdiagram[circular diagram]{Blah, Blah, Blah}` in the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(7,6)
  \psset{
    dimen = m,
    fillstyle = solid,
    fillcolor = blue!60,
    framearc = 0.2
  }
  \pspolygon(0.7,1.5)(2.8,4.5)(3.4,4.5)(1.3,1.5)
  \pspolygon(6.3,1.5)(5.7,1.5)(3.6,4.5)(4.2,4.5)
  \pspolygon(2,0.5)(2,1)(5,1)(5,0.5)
  \psframe[fillcolor = green!50](0,0)(2,1.5)
  \rput(1,0.75){Fish}
  \psframe[fillcolor = yellow!50](5,0)(7,1.5)
  \rput(6,0.75){Bird}
  \psframe[fillcolor = purple!50](2.5,4.5)(4.5,6)
  \rput(3.5,5.25){Mammal}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 4):

Not *exactly* the image in the question - but pretty close. Their wool needs to be combed out to straighten it a bit, but they're all in the right places. Just in need of a bit of a trim, really.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols,shapes.callouts,backgrounds,shadows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    defaid/.style={cloud, fill=#1!25, drop shadow, draw, minimum width=65pt, minimum height=50pt, thick, label={[cloud, fill=#1!25, cloud puffs=5, anchor=south west, label distance=7.5pt, drop shadow, inner sep=10pt, draw, thick]180:{}}, label={[text centered, ellipse callout, drop shadow, anchor=south east, fill=white, draw, yshift=5pt, font=\sffamily\bfseries]160:Baa}},
    coes/.style={line cap=round, line width=2.5pt, draw},
  ]
  \node (d1) [defaid=orange!50!yellow] {};
  \node (d2) [defaid=red] at (-60:3) {};
  \node (d3) [defaid=green!50!black] at (-120:3) {};
  \scoped[on background layer]{%
    \draw [line width=1pt, double=blue!75!black, double distance=5pt] (0,0) -- (240:3) -- (300:3) -- cycle ;
    \foreach \i in {1,...,3}
    \draw [coes] (d\i.-100) ++(-2.5pt,-10pt) -- ++(2.5pt,20pt) -- ++(1.5pt,-20pt) (d\i.-80) ++(2.5pt,-10pt) -- ++(-2.5pt,20pt) -- ++(-1.5pt,-20pt);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: 3 defaid]

Comment: Uhm why sheep? :D

Comment: @Alenanno Bla bla bla -> Baa, baa, baa. Admittedly, they should really be black but you've got to allow a little artistic licence now and again. Also, look closely at the image [in this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115507/). Coincidence? Baa!