# improve the code for a rabbit

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code for a rabbit. Could you help to improve it?
[image]

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgf,tikz}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[ultra thick] (8.487120635907601,5.055577303411975)-- (8.653420477717171,5.393068158849042)-- (8.897979068613598,5.784361904283323)-- (9.054496566787309,6.151199790627962)-- (9.176775862235523,6.635425800602885)-- (9.31861984495545,7.222366418754307)-- (9.343075704045093,7.8728922705388)-- (9.308837501319593,8.293533046880652)-- (9.157211174963809,8.538091637777077)-- (8.85395852225224,8.391356483239223)-- (8.443100089546245,7.956042191443585)-- (8.076262203201606,7.579421961463089)-- (7.748553691400395,7.232148762390164)-- (7.4501922105067555,6.811507986048312)-- (7.279001196879258,6.459343615157459)-- (7.176286588702759,6.038702838815606)-- (7.773848252993539,7.404007626215198)-- (7.819564427995601,7.651505539157395)-- (7.8264669877139506,7.867492374912536)-- (7.804077433222327,8.056204334199078)-- (7.727313246393903,8.254511816839173)-- (7.608968458366749,8.372856604866326)-- (7.465035608063454,8.414437206065056)-- (7.285919172130465,8.38245212821988)-- (7.0716191505677815,8.216129723424961)-- (6.863716144574133,7.944256561740961)-- (6.738974340977944,7.649993845565335)-- (6.665408661934038,7.4548848707097575)-- (6.668607169718555,7.090254983274744)-- (6.646217615226932,6.610478815597094)-- (6.604737979609691,6.154467171231563)-- (6.5529724229494555,5.787402314913527)-- (6.463559188718139,5.5756341285761994)-- (6.1529658487567245,5.330924224364176)-- (5.757665234260378,5.114450078330462)-- (5.354877070877689,4.897975137756692)-- (5.,4.5)-- (4.821479324121693,4.163687330534155)-- (4.6136620201907865,3.858888618102158)-- (4.530535098618423,3.6372168272425243)-- (4.436895027217463,3.5000557234720557)-- (4.349819298957242,3.3215504805386034)-- (4.317165900859659,3.1365145579856346)-- (4.328050366892187,2.9471248490196547)-- (4.347642405750737,2.7707964992927083)-- (4.450381667535669,2.5159314321415236)-- (4.532041887458237,2.3563228204746856)-- (4.7881580317608385,2.2264088342342356)-- (5.059121488776634,2.0779357071022933)-- (5.344932258505623,1.899767954543962)-- (5.484652825467143,1.8292695614504035)-- (5.506329987815211,1.737194466087021)-- (5.476711191510275,1.4854346974950627)-- (5.617400473958722,1.0966879959927742)-- (5.958016631465489,0.27106404899267567)-- (6.269309791973645,-0.2515451024553113)-- (6.6694882347995845,-0.7059850290542589)-- (7.07644936309715,-0.96372707697605)-- (7.395235580263576,-1.0315539316923108)-- (7.496975862337968,-1.1400768992383281);

    \draw (7.496975862337968,-1.1400768992383281)-- (7.5,-1.5)-- (7.35453946743382,-1.7573012771563017)-- (7.0696666776255235,-1.8522588737590668)-- (6.696618976686088,-1.9607818413050841)-- (6.506703783480558,-2.1778277763971188)-- (6.330353961218279,-2.367742969602649)-- (6.316788590275027,-2.5780062192230577)-- (7.083232048568776,-2.6187023320528144)-- (7.754717910259759,-2.6187023320528144)-- (8.236288578745212,-2.5712235337514318)-- (8.453334513837248,-2.354177598659397)-- (8.751772674588796,-2.0693048088511015)-- (8.98916666609571,-1.8115627609293103)-- (9.165516488357987,-1.540255342064267)-- (9.33447506356106,-1.3968710396354151)-- (9.6,-1.4)-- (9.883136971295853,-1.5659555269247534)-- (10.228207353518993,-1.7660963486141739)-- (10.664976183641343,-1.9674263178593647)-- (10.841494002882714,-2.0195793099079515)-- (10.973882367313742,-2.0998146822903925)-- (10.921729375265155,-2.2482501211979082)-- (10.941788218360765,-2.4287797090584)-- (11.142376649316867,-2.60529752829977)-- (11.59570650327766,-2.653438751729235)-- (12.237589482337189,-2.617332834157136)-- (12.662836955964126,-2.5772151479659158)-- (13.148260958877895,-2.505003312821719)-- (14.344478214484807,-2.502493194173754)-- (15.369243602427948,-2.3819325602980905)-- (15.851486137930603,-1.759035951940496)-- (16.18302788108868,-0.8548311978730202)-- (15.640505028648192,-0.9151115148108518)-- (15.781159101503134,-0.1515608335983167)-- (15.469710797324336,0.9736717492412088)-- (14.746346994070354,2.1089510515703727)-- (13.741901035087823,3.0462093916695716)-- (12.74202561081047,3.652194497292207)-- (11.620953165408594,4.04608481594692)-- (10.378683698882188,4.076384071228052)-- (9.424257157526535,3.8794389119006953)-- (8.833421679544463,3.833990028978998)-- (8.484980243811448,4.030935188306354)-- (8.257735829202957,4.364226996398804)-- (8.247996636798005,4.764611473259732)-- (8.487120635907601,5.055577303411975);


    \draw (10.970355256269126,-1.9322725401224543)-- (11.047142365016613,-1.7786983226274815)-- (11.215647409212487,-1.6443208823193802)-- (11.492934190800634,-1.5440710458990508)-- (11.787284774332665,-1.5355391449271076)-- (12.077369407378725,-1.4886136895814215)-- (12.416294906384667,-1.4948048149804178)-- (12.799824433796168,-1.5628503762953614)-- (13.090564559414563,-1.714406399224099)-- (13.310166143658245,-1.8845203025114576);

    \draw[ultra thick] (6.176715812497315,3.9442760413021656)-- (6.433821047703658,3.9250890834509464)-- (6.671739325058781,3.963462999153385)-- (6.834828466794148,4.115039966178019)-- (6.8309910752239045,4.35295824353314)-- (6.712031936546342,4.475754773780944)-- (6.512487574893659,4.535234343119725)-- (6.3263740837368285,4.483429556921433)-- (6.159447550431217,4.329933894111677)-- (6.14217928836512,4.180275622872165)-- (6.16136624621634,4.045966917913629)-- (6.1460166799353635,3.932763866591434);

    \draw[ultra thick] (4.9,3.4)-- (4.867460280572349,3.253821969982106)-- (4.719583397599846,3.1622025968360994)-- (4.623141952182997,3.0657611514192507)-- (4.507412217682777,3.138092235481887)-- (4.404541342571471,3.3149015520794434);

    \draw[ultra thick] (4.652234498957524,2.8886104804097017)-- (4.769852024033724,2.977169558114133)-- (4.9137605253034256,3.1487527711664685)-- (4.978796097992618,3.29266127243616[![enter image description here][1]][1]95);

    \draw[ultra thick] (4.589966397446596,2.870621917750989)-- (4.4751163435486605,2.945343639564103)-- (4.40316209291381,3.072647313764223)-- (4.378254852309438,3.220707021801319);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean by improving? Otherwise, use `smooth` in `\draw` options.

Comment: I prefer the rabbit drawn in the style that cfr drew a tortoise on this web.

Comment: One improvement would be to remove the `[![enter image description here][1]][1]` in line 16 of your MWE.

Comment: @marmot: The rabbit is from the species Rabbitus Httpiensis ;-)

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=41977522#41977522

Comment: define "improve" what do you want the final thing to look like, and why tikz, for example why not `\includegraphics` with [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NynTP.png)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXshr.png

Comment: The tortoise was drawn from scratch, I'm pretty sure, and not converted. (I'm assuming the MWE is the result of conversion, given the numbers of decimal places involved).

Comment: Tortoise code for reference, I guess: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273473/.

Answer (score 8):

There is a very simple way to make the rabbit more smooth. (I did *not* say rabbit smoothie ;-) Just replace `X -- Y -- Z --` by `X .. controls Y and Z ..`. This can be done by a regex search & replace. In general, of course, this will deform the path uncontrollably, but given the high number of points you use it makes the path just smoother. Unfortunately, you have broken up the path at some points, so there are still unwanted corners.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[ultra thick] (8.487120635907601,5.055577303411975) .. controls  (8.653420477717171,5.393068158849042) and  (8.897979068613598,5.784361904283323) .. (9.054496566787309,6.151199790627962) .. controls  (9.176775862235523,6.635425800602885) and  (9.31861984495545,7.222366418754307) .. (9.343075704045093,7.8728922705388) .. controls  (9.308837501319593,8.293533046880652) and  (9.157211174963809,8.538091637777077) .. (8.85395852225224,8.391356483239223) .. controls  (8.443100089546245,7.956042191443585) and  (8.076262203201606,7.579421961463089) .. (7.748553691400395,7.232148762390164) .. controls  (7.4501922105067555,6.811507986048312) and  (7.279001196879258,6.459343615157459) .. (7.176286588702759,6.038702838815606) .. controls  (7.773848252993539,7.404007626215198) and  (7.819564427995601,7.651505539157395) .. (7.8264669877139506,7.867492374912536) .. controls  (7.804077433222327,8.056204334199078) and  (7.727313246393903,8.254511816839173) .. (7.608968458366749,8.372856604866326) .. controls  (7.465035608063454,8.414437206065056) and  (7.285919172130465,8.38245212821988) .. (7.0716191505677815,8.216129723424961) .. controls  (6.863716144574133,7.944256561740961) and  (6.738974340977944,7.649993845565335) .. (6.665408661934038,7.4548848707097575) .. controls  (6.668607169718555,7.090254983274744) and  (6.646217615226932,6.610478815597094) .. (6.604737979609691,6.154467171231563) .. controls  (6.5529724229494555,5.787402314913527) and  (6.463559188718139,5.5756341285761994) .. (6.1529658487567245,5.330924224364176) .. controls  (5.757665234260378,5.114450078330462) and  (5.354877070877689,4.897975137756692) .. (5.,4.5) .. controls  (4.821479324121693,4.163687330534155) and  (4.6136620201907865,3.858888618102158) .. (4.530535098618423,3.6372168272425243) .. controls  (4.436895027217463,3.5000557234720557) and  (4.349819298957242,3.3215504805386034) .. (4.317165900859659,3.1365145579856346) .. controls  (4.328050366892187,2.9471248490196547) and  (4.347642405750737,2.7707964992927083) .. (4.450381667535669,2.5159314321415236) .. controls  (4.532041887458237,2.3563228204746856) and  (4.7881580317608385,2.2264088342342356) .. (5.059121488776634,2.0779357071022933) .. controls  (5.344932258505623,1.899767954543962) and  (5.484652825467143,1.8292695614504035) .. (5.506329987815211,1.737194466087021) .. controls  (5.476711191510275,1.4854346974950627) and  (5.617400473958722,1.0966879959927742) .. (5.958016631465489,0.27106404899267567) .. controls  (6.269309791973645,-0.2515451024553113) and  (6.6694882347995845,-0.7059850290542589) .. (7.07644936309715,-0.96372707697605)-- (7.395235580263576,-1.0315539316923108)-- (7.496975862337968,-1.1400768992383281);

\draw[ultra thick] (7.496975862337968,-1.1400768992383281) .. controls  (7.5,-1.5) and  (7.35453946743382,-1.7573012771563017) .. (7.0696666776255235,-1.8522588737590668) .. controls  (6.696618976686088,-1.9607818413050841) and  (6.506703783480558,-2.1778277763971188) .. (6.330353961218279,-2.367742969602649) .. controls  (6.316788590275027,-2.5780062192230577) and  (7.083232048568776,-2.6187023320528144) .. (7.754717910259759,-2.6187023320528144) .. controls  (8.236288578745212,-2.5712235337514318) and  (8.453334513837248,-2.354177598659397) .. (8.751772674588796,-2.0693048088511015) .. controls  (8.98916666609571,-1.8115627609293103) and  (9.165516488357987,-1.540255342064267) .. (9.33447506356106,-1.3968710396354151) .. controls  (9.6,-1.4) and  (9.883136971295853,-1.5659555269247534) .. (10.228207353518993,-1.7660963486141739) .. controls  (10.664976183641343,-1.9674263178593647) and  (10.841494002882714,-2.0195793099079515) .. (10.973882367313742,-2.0998146822903925) .. controls  (10.921729375265155,-2.2482501211979082) and  (10.941788218360765,-2.4287797090584) .. (11.142376649316867,-2.60529752829977) .. controls  (11.59570650327766,-2.653438751729235) and  (12.237589482337189,-2.617332834157136) .. (12.662836955964126,-2.5772151479659158) .. controls  (13.148260958877895,-2.505003312821719) and  (14.344478214484807,-2.502493194173754) .. (15.369243602427948,-2.3819325602980905) .. controls  (15.851486137930603,-1.759035951940496) and  (16.18302788108868,-0.8548311978730202) .. (15.640505028648192,-0.9151115148108518) .. controls  (15.781159101503134,-0.1515608335983167) and  (15.469710797324336,0.9736717492412088) .. (14.746346994070354,2.1089510515703727) .. controls  (13.741901035087823,3.0462093916695716) and  (12.74202561081047,3.652194497292207) .. (11.620953165408594,4.04608481594692) .. controls  (10.378683698882188,4.076384071228052) and  (9.424257157526535,3.8794389119006953) .. (8.833421679544463,3.833990028978998) .. controls  (8.484980243811448,4.030935188306354) and  (8.257735829202957,4.364226996398804) .. (8.247996636798005,4.764611473259732)-- (8.487120635907601,5.055577303411975);

\draw[ultra thick] (10.970355256269126,-1.9322725401224543) .. controls  (11.047142365016613,-1.7786983226274815) and  (11.215647409212487,-1.6443208823193802) .. (11.492934190800634,-1.5440710458990508) .. controls  (11.787284774332665,-1.5355391449271076) and  (12.077369407378725,-1.4886136895814215) .. (12.416294906384667,-1.4948048149804178) .. controls  (12.799824433796168,-1.5628503762953614) and  (13.090564559414563,-1.714406399224099) .. (13.310166143658245,-1.8845203025114576);

\draw[ultra thick] (6.176715812497315,3.9442760413021656) .. controls  (6.433821047703658,3.9250890834509464) and  (6.671739325058781,3.963462999153385) .. (6.834828466794148,4.115039966178019) .. controls  (6.8309910752239045,4.35295824353314) and  (6.712031936546342,4.475754773780944) .. (6.512487574893659,4.535234343119725) .. controls  (6.3263740837368285,4.483429556921433) and  (6.159447550431217,4.329933894111677) .. (6.14217928836512,4.180275622872165)-- (6.16136624621634,4.045966917913629)-- (6.1460166799353635,3.932763866591434);

\draw[ultra thick] (4.9,3.4) .. controls  (4.867460280572349,3.253821969982106) and  (4.719583397599846,3.1622025968360994) .. (4.623141952182997,3.0657611514192507)-- (4.507412217682777,3.138092235481887)-- (4.404541342571471,3.3149015520794434);

\draw[ultra thick] (4.652234498957524,2.8886104804097017) .. controls  (4.769852024033724,2.977169558114133) and  (4.9137605253034256,3.1487527711664685) .. (4.978796097992618,3.2926612724361695);

\draw[ultra thick] (4.589966397446596,2.870621917750989) .. controls  (4.4751163435486605,2.945343639564103) and  (4.40316209291381,3.072647313764223) .. (4.378254852309438,3.220707021801319);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: I found that there is a much more elegant way, based on the `hobby` package, which emerged from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55558/121799).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%\draw[step=.5cm,gray,very thin] (4,9) grid (16.5,-3);
\draw[ultra thick] (8.487120635907601,5.055577303411975) to[curve through={(8.653420477717171,5.393068158849042) ..  (8.897979068613598,5.784361904283323).. (9.054496566787309,6.151199790627962) ..  (9.176775862235523,6.635425800602885) ..  (9.31861984495545,7.222366418754307).. (9.343075704045093,7.8728922705388) ..  (9.308837501319593,8.293533046880652) ..   (9.157211174963809,8.538091637777077).. (8.85395852225224,8.391356483239223)  ..  (8.443100089546245,7.956042191443585) ..   (8.076262203201606,7.579421961463089).. (7.748553691400395,7.232148762390164)  ..  (7.4501922105067555,6.811507986048312) ..   (7.479001196879258,6.459343615157459) .. (7.773848252993539,7.404007626215198) ..  (7.8264669877139506,7.867492374912536) ..  (7.804077433222327,8.056204334199078) ..   (7.727313246393903,8.254511816839173).. (7.608968458366749,8.372856604866326)  ..  (7.465035608063454,8.414437206065056) ..   (7.285919172130465,8.38245212821988).. (7.0716191505677815,8.216129723424961)  ..  (6.863716144574133,7.944256561740961) ..   (6.738974340977944,7.649993845565335)..  (6.665408661934038,7.4548848707097575) ..   (6.668607169718555,7.090254983274744) ..   (6.646217615226932,6.610478815597094).. (6.604737979609691,6.154467171231563)  ..  (6.5529724229494555,5.787402314913527) ..  (6.463559188718139,5.5756341285761994) .. (6.1529658487567245,5.330924224364176) ..   (5.757665234260378,5.114450078330462) ..   (5.354877070877689,4.897975137756692).. (5.,4.5) ..    (4.821479324121693,4.163687330534155) ..  (4.6136620201907865,3.858888618102158) .. (4.530535098618423,3.6372168272425243) ..   (4.436895027217463,3.5000557234720557) ..  (4.349819298957242,3.3215504805386034) .. (4.317165900859659,3.1365145579856346) ..   (4.328050366892187,2.9471248490196547) ..  (4.347642405750737,2.7707964992927083) .. (4.450381667535669,2.5159314321415236) ..   (4.532041887458237,2.3563228204746856) ..  (4.7881580317608385,2.2264088342342356) .. (5.059121488776634,2.0779357071022933) ..   (5.344932258505623,1.899767954543962) ..  (5.484652825467143,1.8292695614504035) ..  (5.506329987815211,1.737194466087021)..    (5.476711191510275,1.4854346974950627) ..  (5.617400473958722,1.0966879959927742) .. (5.958016631465489,0.27106404899267567) ..   (6.269309791973645,-0.2515451024553113) ..  (6.6694882347995845,-0.7059850290542589) .. (7.07644936309715,-0.96372707697605).. (7.395235580263576,-1.0315539316923108)}] (7.496975862337968,-1.1400768992383281);
\draw[ultra thick] (7.496975862337968,-1.1400768992383281) to[curve through={(7.5,-1.5) ..  (7.35453946743382,-1.7573012771563017) .. (7.0696666776255235,-1.8522588737590668) ..   (6.696618976686088,-1.9607818413050841) ..  (6.506703783480558,-2.1778277763971188) .. (6.330353961218279,-2.367742969602649) ..   (6.316788590275027,-2.5780062192230577) ..  (7.083232048568776,-2.6187023320528144) .. (7.754717910259759,-2.6187023320528144) ..   (8.236288578745212,-2.5712235337514318) ..  (8.453334513837248,-2.354177598659397) .. (8.751772674588796,-2.0693048088511015) ..   (8.98916666609571,-1.8115627609293103) ..  (9.165516488357987,-1.540255342064267) .. (9.33447506356106,-1.3968710396354151) ..   (9.6,-1.4) ..  (9.883136971295853,-1.5659555269247534) .. (10.228207353518993,-1.7660963486141739) ..   (10.664976183641343,-1.9674263178593647) ..  (10.841494002882714,-2.0195793099079515) .. (10.973882367313742,-2.0998146822903925) ..   (10.921729375265155,-2.2482501211979082) ..  (10.941788218360765,-2.4287797090584) .. (11.142376649316867,-2.60529752829977) ..   (11.59570650327766,-2.653438751729235) ..  (12.237589482337189,-2.617332834157136) .. (12.662836955964126,-2.5772151479659158) ..   (13.148260958877895,-2.505003312821719) ..  (14.344478214484807,-2.502493194173754) .. (15.369243602427948,-2.3819325602980905) ..   (15.851486137930603,-1.759035951940496) ..  (16.18302788108868,-0.8548311978730202) .. (15.640505028648192,-0.9151115148108518) ..   (15.781159101503134,-0.1515608335983167) ..  (15.469710797324336,0.9736717492412088) .. (14.746346994070354,2.1089510515703727) ..   (13.741901035087823,3.0462093916695716) ..  (12.74202561081047,3.652194497292207) .. (11.620953165408594,4.04608481594692) ..   (10.378683698882188,4.076384071228052) ..  (9.424257157526535,3.8794389119006953) .. (8.833421679544463,3.833990028978998) ..   (8.484980243811448,4.030935188306354) ..  (8.257735829202957,4.364226996398804) .. (8.247996636798005,4.764611473259732)}] (8.487120635907601,5.055577303411975);

\draw[ultra thick] (10.970355256269126,-1.9322725401224543) to[curve through={   (11.047142365016613,-1.7786983226274815) ..  (11.215647409212487,-1.6443208823193802) .. (11.492934190800634,-1.5440710458990508) ..   (11.787284774332665,-1.5355391449271076) ..  (12.077369407378725,-1.4886136895814215) .. (12.416294906384667,-1.4948048149804178) ..   (12.799824433796168,-1.5628503762953614) ..  (13.090564559414563,-1.714406399224099) }] (13.310166143658245,-1.8845203025114576);

\draw[ultra thick] (6.176715812497315,3.9442760413021656) to[curve through={   (6.433821047703658,3.9250890834509464) ..  (6.671739325058781,3.963462999153385) .. (6.834828466794148,4.115039966178019) ..   (6.8309910752239045,4.35295824353314) ..  (6.712031936546342,4.475754773780944) .. (6.512487574893659,4.535234343119725) ..   (6.3263740837368285,4.483429556921433) ..  (6.159447550431217,4.329933894111677) .. (6.14217928836512,4.180275622872165).. (6.16136624621634,4.045966917913629)}] (6.1460166799353635,3.932763866591434);

\draw[ultra thick] (4.9,3.4) to[curve through={   (4.867460280572349,3.253821969982106) ..  (4.719583397599846,3.1622025968360994) .. (4.623141952182997,3.0657611514192507).. (4.507412217682777,3.138092235481887)}] (4.404541342571471,3.3149015520794434);

\draw[ultra thick] (4.652234498957524,2.8886104804097017) to[curve through={   (4.769852024033724,2.977169558114133) ..  (4.9137605253034256,3.1487527711664685) }] (4.978796097992618,3.2926612724361695);

\draw[ultra thick] (4.589966397446596,2.870621917750989) to[curve through={   (4.4751163435486605,2.945343639564103) ..  (4.40316209291381,3.072647313764223) }] (4.378254852309438,3.220707021801319);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This looks much smoother now, the only problem are the ears. This problem would not arise if you were to draw a marmot (who has shorter ears;-).

With the built-in smooth plot option, the ears look much better, but the tail gets worse...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[ultra thick,smooth] plot coordinates {(8.487120635907601,5.055577303411975)  (8.653420477717171,5.393068158849042)  (8.897979068613598,5.784361904283323)  (9.054496566787309,6.151199790627962)  (9.176775862235523,6.635425800602885)  (9.31861984495545,7.222366418754307)  (9.343075704045093,7.8728922705388)  (9.308837501319593,8.293533046880652)  (9.157211174963809,8.538091637777077)  (8.85395852225224,8.391356483239223)  (8.443100089546245,7.956042191443585)  (8.076262203201606,7.579421961463089)  (7.748553691400395,7.232148762390164)  (7.4501922105067555,6.811507986048312)  (7.279001196879258,6.459343615157459)  (7.176286588702759,6.038702838815606)  (7.773848252993539,7.404007626215198)  (7.819564427995601,7.651505539157395)  (7.8264669877139506,7.867492374912536)  (7.804077433222327,8.056204334199078)  (7.727313246393903,8.254511816839173)  (7.608968458366749,8.372856604866326)  (7.465035608063454,8.414437206065056)  (7.285919172130465,8.38245212821988)  (7.0716191505677815,8.216129723424961)  (6.863716144574133,7.944256561740961)  (6.738974340977944,7.649993845565335)  (6.665408661934038,7.4548848707097575)  (6.668607169718555,7.090254983274744)  (6.646217615226932,6.610478815597094)  (6.604737979609691,6.154467171231563)  (6.5529724229494555,5.787402314913527)  (6.463559188718139,5.5756341285761994)  (6.1529658487567245,5.330924224364176)  (5.757665234260378,5.114450078330462)  (5.354877070877689,4.897975137756692)  (5.,4.5)  (4.821479324121693,4.163687330534155)  (4.6136620201907865,3.858888618102158)  (4.530535098618423,3.6372168272425243)  (4.436895027217463,3.5000557234720557)  (4.349819298957242,3.3215504805386034)  (4.317165900859659,3.1365145579856346)  (4.328050366892187,2.9471248490196547)  (4.347642405750737,2.7707964992927083)  (4.450381667535669,2.5159314321415236)  (4.532041887458237,2.3563228204746856)  (4.7881580317608385,2.2264088342342356)  (5.059121488776634,2.0779357071022933)  (5.344932258505623,1.899767954543962)  (5.484652825467143,1.8292695614504035)  (5.506329987815211,1.737194466087021)  (5.476711191510275,1.4854346974950627)  (5.617400473958722,1.0966879959927742)  (5.958016631465489,0.27106404899267567)  (6.269309791973645,-0.2515451024553113)  (6.6694882347995845,-0.7059850290542589)  (7.07644936309715,-0.96372707697605)  (7.395235580263576,-1.0315539316923108)  (7.496975862337968,-1.1400768992383281)};

\draw[ultra thick,smooth] plot coordinates { (7.496975862337968,-1.1400768992383281)  (7.5,-1.5)  (7.35453946743382,-1.7573012771563017)  (7.0696666776255235,-1.8522588737590668)  (6.696618976686088,-1.9607818413050841)  (6.506703783480558,-2.1778277763971188)  (6.330353961218279,-2.367742969602649)  (6.316788590275027,-2.5780062192230577)  (7.083232048568776,-2.6187023320528144)  (7.754717910259759,-2.6187023320528144)  (8.236288578745212,-2.5712235337514318)  (8.453334513837248,-2.354177598659397)  (8.751772674588796,-2.0693048088511015)  (8.98916666609571,-1.8115627609293103)  (9.165516488357987,-1.540255342064267)  (9.33447506356106,-1.3968710396354151)  (9.6,-1.4)  (9.883136971295853,-1.5659555269247534)  (10.228207353518993,-1.7660963486141739)  (10.664976183641343,-1.9674263178593647)  (10.841494002882714,-2.0195793099079515)  (10.973882367313742,-2.0998146822903925)  (10.921729375265155,-2.2482501211979082)  (10.941788218360765,-2.4287797090584)  (11.142376649316867,-2.60529752829977)  (11.59570650327766,-2.653438751729235)  (12.237589482337189,-2.617332834157136)  (12.662836955964126,-2.5772151479659158)  (13.148260958877895,-2.505003312821719)  (14.344478214484807,-2.502493194173754)  (15.369243602427948,-2.3819325602980905)  (15.851486137930603,-1.759035951940496)  (16.18302788108868,-0.8548311978730202)  (15.640505028648192,-0.9151115148108518)  (15.781159101503134,-0.1515608335983167)  (15.469710797324336,0.9736717492412088)  (14.746346994070354,2.1089510515703727)  (13.741901035087823,3.0462093916695716)  (12.74202561081047,3.652194497292207)  (11.620953165408594,4.04608481594692)  (10.378683698882188,4.076384071228052)  (9.424257157526535,3.8794389119006953)  (8.833421679544463,3.833990028978998)  (8.484980243811448,4.030935188306354)  (8.257735829202957,4.364226996398804)  (8.247996636798005,4.764611473259732)  (8.487120635907601,5.055577303411975)};

\draw[ultra thick,smooth] plot coordinates { (10.970355256269126,-1.9322725401224543)  (11.047142365016613,-1.7786983226274815)  (11.215647409212487,-1.6443208823193802)  (11.492934190800634,-1.5440710458990508)  (11.787284774332665,-1.5355391449271076)  (12.077369407378725,-1.4886136895814215)  (12.416294906384667,-1.4948048149804178)  (12.799824433796168,-1.5628503762953614)  (13.090564559414563,-1.714406399224099)  (13.310166143658245,-1.8845203025114576)};

\draw[ultra thick,smooth] plot coordinates { (6.176715812497315,3.9442760413021656)  (6.433821047703658,3.9250890834509464)  (6.671739325058781,3.963462999153385)  (6.834828466794148,4.115039966178019)  (6.8309910752239045,4.35295824353314)  (6.712031936546342,4.475754773780944)  (6.512487574893659,4.535234343119725)  (6.3263740837368285,4.483429556921433)  (6.159447550431217,4.329933894111677)  (6.14217928836512,4.180275622872165)  (6.16136624621634,4.045966917913629)  (6.1460166799353635,3.932763866591434)};

\draw[ultra thick,smooth] plot coordinates { (4.9,3.4)  (4.867460280572349,3.253821969982106)  (4.719583397599846,3.1622025968360994)  (4.623141952182997,3.0657611514192507)  (4.507412217682777,3.138092235481887)  (4.404541342571471,3.3149015520794434)};

\draw[ultra thick,smooth] plot coordinates { (4.652234498957524,2.8886104804097017)  (4.769852024033724,2.977169558114133)  (4.9137605253034256,3.1487527711664685)  (4.978796097992618,3.2926612724361695)};

\draw[ultra thick,smooth] plot coordinates { (4.589966397446596,2.870621917750989)  (4.4751163435486605,2.945343639564103)  (4.40316209291381,3.072647313764223)  (4.378254852309438,3.220707021801319)};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273473/101651

Comment: @CarLaTeX Grazie! Sadly marmots seem to be underrepresented in this forum ;-)

Comment: I think you should add the link to your answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387146/101651

Comment: I have no idea what a marmot looks like. Hence, I don't know whether they are underrepresented or not.

Answer (score 4):

Converted from image to `tikz` using inkscape:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=-1.000000, xscale=1.000000, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\path[fill=black,line width=0.212pt] (82.5674,75.5849) .. controls (85.7411,76.9768) and (82.0664,87.7459) .. (82.0107,92.1489) .. controls (80.5733,100.1051) and (79.4572,102.9102) .. (74.6707,109.4490) .. controls (71.4154,114.3827) and (78.0329,120.9167) .. (83.2332,119.1247) .. controls (89.0434,118.2483) and (94.7744,116.5355) .. (100.7067,117.1800) .. controls (120.8817,117.6007) and (134.8787,132.1636) .. (144.2820,147.3390) .. controls (146.1343,152.7719) and (148.3811,158.4917) .. (146.5867,164.2316) .. controls (146.5198,167.6616) and (153.2623,163.7725) .. (150.5725,168.5797) .. controls (148.3883,173.3249) and (146.3915,180.5117) .. (140.4855,181.0726) .. controls (130.9141,182.1718) and (121.2585,181.7993) .. (111.6734,182.6946) .. controls (105.3965,182.7537) and (99.8801,184.9868) .. (98.8666,177.0171) .. controls (93.3472,176.5982) and (87.7614,168.1063) .. (82.4465,172.7630) .. controls (79.6602,176.4211) and (76.4300,180.8276) .. (72.3542,182.6559) .. controls (66.7276,182.6340) and (58.8188,183.9473) .. (54.5977,181.7328) .. controls (55.0193,175.1486) and (63.7928,176.5087) .. (65.9692,171.8127) .. controls (67.1188,165.5333) and (58.6354,165.3787) .. (55.6001,161.5918) .. controls (49.4814,153.9578) and (48.2561,137.4571) .. (40.0411,136.7050) .. controls (34.2819,135.1458) and (34.4466,128.0901) .. (35.8772,123.4981) .. controls (38.1840,116.0524) and (43.2671,108.9741) .. (50.6787,106.0193) .. controls (57.3926,103.7052) and (57.8091,96.2871) .. (57.7640,90.2587) .. controls (57.4566,84.6846) and (58.8020,77.8309) .. (64.2082,75.0401) .. controls (71.5410,72.2045) and (69.8166,86.3591) .. (70.9719,86.4958) .. controls (75.0357,82.7046) and (77.9005,73.5381) .. (82.5674,75.5849) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]