# Aquatic animals in 2D or 3D

Tags: tikz-pgf, fun

In relation to these beautiful questions and answers,

["The duck pond": showcase of TikZ-drawn animals/ducks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387047/the-duck-pond-showcase-of-tikz-drawn-animals-ducks)

[animal icons in Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273361/animal-icons-in-tikz)

in this period I'm searching if exists between the various distributions of LaTeX provide a particular package where you can directly draw animals or, in particular, different aquatic animals in 2D or 3D (for example like whales with the whole body, ...) through commands. I don't currently know if it is being planned by some user.

Thank you.

Comment: **BREAKING NEWS:** `tikzfish` is going to be released or becoming a part of `tikzlings`

Comment: How about https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/361547/121799?

Comment: @marmot It is wonderful, but there is not a package yet. @ samcarter ^^

Comment: @JouleV Does a penguin qualify as an aquatic animal?

Comment: @marmot Hmm, I got the `Undefined control sequence` error when I use `\dolphin[lovely]`.

Comment: @JouleV I guess `lovely`, `cute` and so on may only work with `\marmot`, where they are set by default, so you do not have to add these keys. ;-)

Comment: @marmot I get errors *again: `I do not know the key '/cute' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.` :) You may want to update your comment.

Comment: @JouleV When I have read your first comment, I thought that it was true.

Comment: @marmot See there: https://www.focusjunior.it/animali/enciclopedia-degli-animali/pinguino-imperatore/ : Although they are to all intents and purposes birds, penguins do not fly and have the characteristics of aquatic animals. I have seen before your link but the fish are drawn with TiKZ. The command `\shark` in 2D is very nice because the body is whole. For the others animal I can see only the face and not the body.

Comment: @Sebastiano Of course penguins do fly see the documentary here http://www.passion-pictures.com/uk/animation-studios/project/bbc-iplayer-penguins/