# How to draw a fish?

Tags: fun

I would like to draw an image like the following.

[image]

This is what I've done so far (I used `tikz`, but any other package is welcome):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[fill=blue] (.5,0) rectangle (4,2);
        \draw[fill=red] (1,1) to[bend left=50] (3,1) to[bend left=50] (1,1);
        \draw[fill=red] (3,1) -- (3.5,1.5) -- (3.3,1) -- (3.5,.5) -- cycle;
        \draw[fill=white] (1.6,1.1) circle (.15cm); 
        \draw[fill=blue] (1.55,1.1) circle (.05cm);         
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit: April 2nd, Time for explanation*

In Italy (but I also think in other countries), a practical joke done on April 1st is called "pesce d'Aprile" (= April's fish, that is an [April Fools' Day prank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Fools%27_Day)) and is often related to fishes.

The usual one is to stick a drawing of a fish on someone's back without he/she realizes it.

Some years ago a colleague of mine stuck some "pesci d'Aprile" with written below "sono disponibile" (= I'm easy) on the rear of all the cars in our company car parking. Some other colleagues didn't realize it, and they had gone around with that drawing for days.

Another funny example happened in Milan [on April, 1st 1985](http://ricerca.repubblica.it/repubblica/archivio/repubblica/1985/04/02/come-pesce-aprile-false-multe-migliaia.html). Someone put on the windshield of a lot of cars a false fine for illegal parking. On the fine sheet was written "per il pagamento rivolgersi agli uffici comunali di via Gadio, 2" (= for payment, please contact the municipal offices in via Gadio, 2), the address of the Civic Aquarium.

Hence, this question was simply a way to put

[image]

P.S. = Since I earned a lot of reputation points with this trick question, I decided to give them back to the Community awarding a bounty to the two answers posted on April, 1st.

Moreover, I accepted Robert's one since he guessed without spoiling, and I thank the other two answerers.

To the downvoters: you're probably technically right, but:

- there's already too much sadness in the world, let's laugh now and then!
- humor is part of the LaTeX philosophy, Prof. Knuth himself *docet*
- if only serious questions are accepted, why did they create a *fun* tag?

Comment: Maybe you should switch to an ellipse for the body (more similar to the upper picture, perhaps also for the tail: two overlapping ellipses) and you could have a look at `decorations`with its `snake` style for the wavy lines. The mouth could be a bended draw as you use it already. And I think the eye looks fine.

Comment: You did it??!!!

Comment: Can you assure me the reason is not religious in any way?

Comment: I'm just suspicious of fish. Usually, mysterious fish turn out to be religiously motivated. But perhaps I've just been unlucky. Sleep well.

Comment: @CarLaTeX, I surely couldn't know who was the user asking this question before scrolling down. But I already knew he/she was from Italy! :D

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis Ma certamente! Comunque anche in Francia dicono pesce d'aprile!

Comment: By the way, I can think of one serious thing only (I hope someone takes it as a suggestion for their asnwers): ... if I only knew how to intentionally set rivers and "holes" in paragraphs, I could have used `shapepar` and the `+100` bounty would have been mine! But this is clearly not the case... XD

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis You can learn it in the future and win the 200 points bounty! :):):):)

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis see Paulo's answer!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A couple of hours late:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern,graphicx,color}
\def\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\def\seriesdefault{\bfdefault}
\def\chihapaura#1#2?{\color{\ifcase#1red\or yellow\or blue\fi}%
       \fontsize{#2\unitlength}{0pt}\selectfont}
\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(50,50)
  \put(46,18) {\chihapaura112?E}
  \put(38,15) {\chihapaura020?C}
  \put(29,5)  {\chihapaura121?\scalebox1[2.5]{S}}
  \put(0,0)   {\chihapaura0100?$\epsilon$}
  \put(7,20)  {\chihapaura230?\rotatebox{-24}{p}}
\end{picture}%(d'aprile)
\end{document}
```

[image: d'aprile]

Comment: sweet! you got my vote :)

Answer (score 58):

[image]

`Asymptote` version:

```
// fish.asy
//
settings.outformat="pdf";
real w=600,h=400; size(h,w);
pen bgPen=rgb(0,0.647,1),
bodyPen=rgb(0.847,0.196,0.133),
whitePen=rgb(1,1,1),
eyePen=rgb(0.004,0.18,1),
mouthPen=rgb(1,1,1),
scalesPen=rgb(0.98,1,0)+12pt;
pair[][] bBody={
    {(454,270),(436,252),(443,251),},{(433,269),(424,286),(398,322),},
    {(361,352),(324,382),(276,405),},{(218,394),(160,382),(92,334),},
    {(55,295),(18,256),(12,226),},{(13,187),(14,149),(21,102),},
    {(65,66),(109,30),(189,3),},{(243,2),(296,1),(322,24),},
    {(348,46),(374,68),(398,89),},{(414,109),(430,129),(437,149),},
    {(450,143),(463,137),(481,105),},{(504,80),(526,55),(552,37),},
    {(568,40),(585,43),(592,66),},{(584,97),(576,128),(553,166),},
    {(542,181),(531,197),(531,189),},{(543,204),(555,218),(579,256),},
    {(585,286),(591,316),(578,339),},{(571,349),(563,359),(561,356),},
    {(538,338),(515,320),(472,287),},
};
pair[][] bWhite={
    {(223,261),(227,278),(209,303),},{(192,312),(174,321),(156,315),},
    {(141,304),(127,293),(115,276),},{(116,260),(118,244),(132,228),},
    {(143,222),(155,215),(162,220),},{(179,227),(195,234),(220,244),},
};
pair[][] bEye={
    {(177,256),(180,264),(177,272),},{(171,276),(164,280),(154,279),},
    {(146,276),(139,272),(135,265),},{(136,258),(138,250),(146,241),},
    {(155,241),(163,240),(173,248),},
};
pair[][] bMouth={
    {(143,104),(122,94),(95,92),},
    {(83,86),(71,81),(75,71),},
    {(81,68),(87,65),(96,69),},
    {(105,68),(115,67),(126,62),},
    {(145,74),(165,87),(194,117),},
    {(204,133),(213,150),(204,152),},
    {(192,143),(179,135),(165,115),},
};
pair[][] aScales={
    {(221,370),(236,366),(257,360),(274,346),(292,337),(310,322),(315,305),(317,292),(312,275),
        (301,264),(307,249),(319,241),(331,229),(340,222),(350,210),(352,194),(347,176),(338,163),
        (335,151),(326,144),(319,141),(307,139),(312,123),(318,110),(322,93),(322,79),(321,63),(315,56),(297,46),(288,44),},
    {(387,115),(393,123),(397,139),(399,153),(394,174),(393,180),(401,203),(403,223),(390,243),
        (373,257),(383,268),(384,281),(379,300),(360,330),(328,354),(319,359),},
    {(465,153),(472,171),(460,182),(461,195),(469,204),(470,219),(460,231),(446,237),(432,242),},
    {(513,111),(520,120),(522,131),(515,143),(507,153),(511,164),(515,174),(510,187),
        (509,205),(511,219),(509,233),(517,243),(521,251),(519,265),(512,280),(507,288),},
    {(547,68),(556,73),(559,83),(559,94),(562,106),(563,112),},
    {(574,286),(567,291),(562,297),(557,301),(563,304),(564,313),(554,318),(546,323),},
};
pen[] penList={bodyPen, whitePen, eyePen, mouthPen};
pair[][][] pointList={bBody, bWhite, bEye, bMouth};
guide buildBguide(pair[][] aPoints){
    int n=aPoints.length;  guide g=aPoints[0][0]; 
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;++i){
        g=g..controls aPoints[i][1] and aPoints[i][2]..aPoints[i+1][0]; 
    }
    return g..controls aPoints[n-1][1] and aPoints[n-1][2]..cycle; 
};
guide buildGuide(pair[] aPoints){
    guide g; for(int i=0;i<aPoints.length;++i)g=g..aPoints[i]; 
    return g;
};
fill(box(0,(w-1,h-1)),bgPen);
for(int i=0;i<pointList.length;++i){
    fill(buildBguide(pointList[i]),penList[i]);
}
for(int i=0;i<aScales.length;++i){
    draw(buildGuide(aScales[i]),scalesPen);
}
```

Run `asy fish` to get `fish.pdf`.

*** Edit: ***
[image]

Just for a little bit more fun, with minimal touch:

```
// fish.asy
//
settings.outformat="pdf";
real w=600,h=400; size(h,w);
pen bgPen=rgb(0,0.647,1),
bodyPen=rgb(0.847,0.196,0.133),
whitePen=rgb(1,1,1),
eyePen=rgb(0.004,0.18,1)+opacity(0.01),
mouthPen=rgb(1,1,1),
scalesPen=rgb(0.98,1,0)+12pt;
pair[][] bBody={
    {(454,270),(436,252),(443,251),},{(433,269),(424,286),(398,322),},
    {(361,352),(324,382),(276,405),},{(218,394),(160,382),(92,334),},
    {(55,295),(18,256),(12,226),},{(13,187),(14,149),(21,102),},
    {(65,66),(109,30),(189,3),},{(243,2),(296,1),(322,24),},
    {(348,46),(374,68),(398,89),},{(414,109),(430,129),(437,149),},
    {(450,143),(463,137),(481,105),},{(504,80),(526,55),(552,37),},
    {(568,40),(585,43),(592,66),},{(584,97),(576,128),(553,166),},
    {(542,181),(531,197),(531,189),},{(543,204),(555,218),(579,256),},
    {(585,286),(591,316),(578,339),},{(571,349),(563,359),(561,356),},
    {(538,338),(515,320),(472,287),},
};
pair[][] bWhite={
    {(223,261),(227,278),(209,303),},{(192,312),(174,321),(156,315),},
    {(141,304),(127,293),(115,276),},{(116,260),(118,244),(132,228),},
    {(143,222),(155,215),(162,220),},{(179,227),(195,234),(220,244),},
};
pair[][] bEye={
    {(177,256),(180,264),(177,272),},{(171,276),(164,280),(154,279),},
    {(146,276),(139,272),(135,265),},{(136,258),(138,250),(146,241),},
    {(155,241),(163,240),(173,248),},
};
pair[][] bMouth={
    {(143,104),(122,94),(95,92),},
    {(83,86),(71,81),(75,71),},
    {(81,68),(87,65),(96,69),},
    {(105,68),(115,67),(126,62),},
    {(145,74),(165,87),(194,117),},
    {(204,133),(213,150),(204,152),},
    {(192,143),(179,135),(165,115),},
};
pair[][] aScales={
    {(221,370),(236,366),(257,360),(274,346),(292,337),(310,322),(315,305),(317,292),(312,275),
        (301,264),(307,249),(319,241),(331,229),(340,222),(350,210),(352,194),(347,176),(338,163),
        (335,151),(326,144),(319,141),(307,139),(312,123),(318,110),(322,93),(322,79),(321,63),(315,56),(297,46),(288,44),},
    {(387,115),(393,123),(397,139),(399,153),(394,174),(393,180),(401,203),(403,223),(390,243),
        (373,257),(383,268),(384,281),(379,300),(360,330),(328,354),(319,359),},
    {(465,153),(472,171),(460,182),(461,195),(469,204),(470,219),(460,231),(446,237),(432,242),},
    {(513,111),(520,120),(522,131),(515,143),(507,153),(511,164),(515,174),(510,187),
        (509,205),(511,219),(509,233),(517,243),(521,251),(519,265),(512,280),(507,288),},
    {(547,68),(556,73),(559,83),(559,94),(562,106),(563,112),},
    {(574,286),(567,291),(562,297),(557,301),(563,304),(564,313),(554,318),(546,323),},
};
guide buildBguide(pair[][] aPoints){
    int n=aPoints.length;  guide g=aPoints[0][0]; 
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;++i){
        g=g..controls aPoints[i][1] and aPoints[i][2]..aPoints[i+1][0]; 
    }
    return g..controls aPoints[n-1][1] and aPoints[n-1][2]..cycle; 
};
guide buildGuide(pair[] aPoints){
    guide g; for(int i=0;i<aPoints.length;++i)g=g..aPoints[i]; 
    return g;
};
axialshade(box(0,(w-1,h-1)),deepblue,(0,3),palegreen,(0,600));
axialshade(buildBguide(bBody),paleyellow+opacity(0.6),(0,3),deepred,(0,200));

guide gWhite=buildBguide(bWhite);
guide gEye=buildBguide(bEye);
pair whiteCenter=(max(gWhite)+min(gWhite))/2;
pair eyeCenter=(max(gEye)+min(gEye))/2;
radialshade(gWhite,white,whiteCenter,20, orange,whiteCenter,60);
radialshade(gEye,black,eyeCenter,6, deepgreen,eyeCenter,20);
fill(buildBguide(bMouth),mouthPen);

for(int i=0;i<aScales.length;++i){
    draw(buildGuide(aScales[i]),scalesPen);
}

int n=99;  real llen=20,s;
pair lpoint,ldir;
for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
    s=i/(n-2);
    lpoint=relpoint(gWhite,s);
    ldir=rotate(90)*reldir(gWhite,s);
    draw(lpoint--(lpoint+llen*sin(2*pi*s)*ldir),black);
}
```

*** Edit-3d ***

More fun, this time in 3d:

[image]

```
// fish3d.asy
//
real w=8cm,h=0.618w;
size(h,w);

import solids;
currentprojection=orthographic(
camera=(-230,60,133),up=three.Y,target=(5,21,2),zoom=0.8);
currentlight=White;

include "fish3d05.asy";

material m_Skin=material(diffusepen=gray(0), emissivepen=rgb(0.8,0,0), specularpen=gray(1),    shininess=0.15);
material m_eyeW=material(diffusepen=gray(0.001), emissivepen=gray(0.45), specularpen=gray(0.9),shininess=0.15);
material m_eyeB=material(diffusepen=gray(0.001), emissivepen=gray(0.01), specularpen=gray(0.9),shininess=0.15);

draw(surface(P),m_Skin);

triple c0=(-42,42,0);
triple c1=(-42,42,-20);
triple c2=(-42,42,22);

real R=10, r=3;
draw(surface(sphere(c1,R)),surfacepen=m_eyeW);
draw(surface(sphere(c2,R)),surfacepen=m_eyeW);

draw(surface(rotate(70,c1-(0,1,0),c1+(0,1,0))*sphere(c1-(R-r*0.62)*(three.Z),r)) ,m_eyeB);
draw(surface(rotate(-60,c2-(0,1,0),c2+(0,1,0))*sphere(c2+(R-r*0.62)*(three.Z),r)),m_eyeB);
```

And the shape in `fish3d05.asy` file:

```
// fish3d05.asy

triple[][][] P={
{{(-77,42,0),(-78,42,7),(-71,37,14),(-68,22,14)},
{(-98,26,0),(-98,27,7),(-91,29,7),(-89,13,7)},
{(-119,20,0),(-119,20,1),(-115,13,5),(-113,7,5)},
{(-87,18,0),(-87,18,1),(-85,13,2),(-83,7,2)},
},{
{(-16,75,0),(-16,74,14),(-11,65,29),(-9,37,30)},
{(-38,80,0),(-38,80,14),(-31,67,31),(-30,39,31)},
{(-57,57,0),(-58,58,7),(-50,45,20),(-47,30,20)},
{(-77,42,0),(-78,42,7),(-71,37,14),(-68,22,14)},
},{
{(49,26,0),(50,26,5),(51,24,9),(51,20,9)},
{(33,34,0),(34,34,5),(35,25,14),(36,22,14)},
{(7,69,0),(7,69,14),(10,63,27),(12,35,28)},
{(-16,75,0),(-16,74,14),(-11,65,29),(-9,37,30)},
},{
{(80,39,-1),(80,39,4),(84,43,9),(83,30,9)},
{(71,36,-1),(71,36,4),(75,41,10),(75,28,10)},
{(65,17,0),(66,17,5),(67,22,5),(67,18,5)},
{(49,26,0),(50,26,5),(51,24,9),(51,20,9)},
},{
{(65,26,0),(66,26,0),(66,23,0),(66,20,0)},
{(101,33,0),(102,33,0),(102,29,2),(102,26,2)},
{(89,43,-1),(89,43,4),(92,46,8),(92,32,8)},
{(80,39,-1),(80,39,4),(84,43,9),(83,30,9)},
},{
{(-87,18,0),(-87,18,1),(-85,13,2),(-83,7,2)},
{(-55,16,0),(-55,16,1),(-56,13,0),(-54,7,0)},
{(29,19,0),(30,19,0),(29,16,-2),(29,14,-2)},
{(65,26,0),(66,26,0),(66,23,0),(66,20,0)},
},{
{(-68,22,14),(-65,6,14),(-67,-20,7),(-67,-21,0)},
{(-89,13,7),(-86,-2,7),(-87,-12,6),(-86,-13,-1)},
{(-113,7,5),(-111,0,5),(-108,-14,1),(-108,-15,0)},
{(-83,7,2),(-81,1,2),(-79,-6,1),(-79,-7,0)},
},{
{(-9,37,30),(-8,9,30),(-10,-39,16),(-10,-38,2)},
{(-30,39,31),(-28,11,32),(-31,-47,16),(-30,-47,2)},
{(-47,30,20),(-45,14,20),(-48,-28,7),(-47,-29,1)},
{(-68,22,14),(-65,6,14),(-67,-20,7),(-67,-21,0)},
},{
{(51,20,9),(52,16,9),(51,10,5),(50,10,0)},
{(36,22,14),(36,18,14),(36,6,5),(35,6,1)},
{(12,35,28),(13,7,28),(10,-30,16),(11,-30,2)},
{(-9,37,30),(-8,9,30),(-10,-39,16),(-10,-38,2)},
},{
{(83,30,9),(83,16,9),(79,-14,5),(79,-14,0)},
{(75,28,10),(74,14,10),(71,-14,5),(71,-14,0)},
{(67,18,5),(67,14,5),(66,14,4),(65,14,-1)},
{(51,20,9),(52,16,9),(51,10,5),(50,10,0)},
},{
{(66,20,0),(66,18,0),(65,15,0),(65,16,0)},
{(102,26,2),(102,24,2),(100,11,0),(99,12,0)},
{(92,32,8),(92,19,9),(88,-15,5),(88,-15,0)},
{(83,30,9),(83,16,9),(79,-14,5),(79,-14,0)},
},{
{(-83,7,2),(-81,1,2),(-79,-6,1),(-79,-7,0)},
{(-54,7,0),(-52,1,0),(-50,2,2),(-50,1,0)},
{(29,14,-2),(29,11,-2),(31,19,0),(31,20,0)},
{(66,20,0),(66,18,0),(65,15,0),(65,16,0)},
},{
{(-67,-21,0),(-66,-22,-7),(-63,3,-14),(-66,18,-14)},
{(-86,-13,-1),(-85,-14,-8),(-84,-7,-9),(-87,9,-9)},
{(-108,-15,0),(-108,-16,-2),(-110,-3,-6),(-112,3,-6)},
{(-79,-7,0),(-79,-8,-1),(-81,-2,-3),(-83,4,-3)},
},{
{(-10,-38,2),(-10,-38,-12),(-7,11,-25),(-8,39,-25)},
{(-30,-47,2),(-30,-47,-12),(-26,12,-26),(-27,40,-27)},
{(-47,-29,1),(-47,-30,-6),(-42,12,-19),(-44,28,-19)},
{(-67,-21,0),(-66,-22,-7),(-63,3,-14),(-66,18,-14)},
},{
{(50,10,0),(49,10,-5),(49,16,-10),(49,20,-10)},
{(35,6,1),(34,6,-4),(33,18,-13),(33,22,-13)},
{(11,-30,2),(11,-29,-12),(13,9,-23),(11,37,-24)},
{(-10,-38,2),(-10,-38,-12),(-7,11,-25),(-8,39,-25)},
},{
{(79,-14,0),(79,-14,-5),(83,16,-10),(83,30,-10)},
{(71,-14,0),(70,-14,-5),(73,14,-11),(74,27,-11)},
{(65,14,-1),(64,14,-5),(64,13,-7),(64,17,-7)},
{(50,10,0),(49,10,-5),(49,16,-10),(49,20,-10)},
},{
{(65,16,0),(65,16,0),(65,18,0),(65,20,0)},
{(99,12,0),(99,12,0),(102,25,-2),(102,27,-2)},
{(88,-15,0),(88,-15,-5),(92,19,-9),(92,32,-9)},
{(79,-14,0),(79,-14,-5),(83,16,-10),(83,30,-10)},
},{
{(-79,-7,0),(-79,-8,-1),(-81,-2,-3),(-83,4,-3)},
{(-50,1,0),(-50,0,-1),(-52,-1,0),(-54,5,0)},
{(31,20,0),(31,20,0),(28,11,2),(28,14,2)},
{(65,16,0),(65,16,0),(65,18,0),(65,20,0)},
},{
{(-66,18,-14),(-68,34,-14),(-77,41,-7),(-77,42,0)},
{(-87,9,-9),(-89,25,-9),(-97,26,-7),(-98,26,0)},
{(-112,3,-6),(-114,9,-6),(-119,19,-1),(-119,20,0)},
{(-83,4,-3),(-85,10,-3),(-87,17,-1),(-87,18,0)},
},{
{(-8,39,-25),(-10,67,-26),(-15,75,-14),(-16,75,0)},
{(-27,40,-27),(-29,68,-27),(-38,81,-14),(-38,80,0)},
{(-44,28,-19),(-47,43,-19),(-57,56,-7),(-57,57,0)},
{(-66,18,-14),(-68,34,-14),(-77,41,-7),(-77,42,0)},
},{
{(49,20,-10),(48,24,-10),(49,26,-5),(49,26,0)},
{(33,22,-13),(33,26,-13),(33,34,-5),(33,34,0)},
{(11,37,-24),(10,66,-24),(7,69,-14),(7,69,0)},
{(-8,39,-25),(-10,67,-26),(-15,75,-14),(-16,75,0)},
},{
{(83,30,-10),(83,43,-10),(80,39,-5),(80,39,-1)},
{(74,27,-11),(74,41,-11),(71,36,-5),(71,36,-1)},
{(64,17,-7),(64,21,-7),(64,17,-5),(65,17,0)},
{(49,20,-10),(48,24,-10),(49,26,-5),(49,26,0)},
},{
{(65,20,0),(65,23,0),(65,26,0),(65,26,0)},
{(102,27,-2),(102,30,-2),(101,33,0),(101,33,0)},
{(92,32,-9),(93,46,-9),(89,43,-5),(89,43,-1)},
{(83,30,-10),(83,43,-10),(80,39,-5),(80,39,-1)},
},{
{(-83,4,-3),(-85,10,-3),(-87,17,-1),(-87,18,0)},
{(-54,5,0),(-56,11,0),(-55,15,-1),(-55,16,0)},
{(28,14,2),(28,16,2),(29,19,0),(29,19,0)},
{(65,20,0),(65,23,0),(65,26,0),(65,26,0)},
}};
```

Comment: +1, gorgeous! Did you use a tool to create this answer? See the edit of my question.

Comment: @CarLaTeX: yes, basically,
`InkScape` to convert `png` to `eps`,
`pstoedit` to convert `eps` to get the basic contours in plain `asy`,
then mostly cleaning a bit.

Comment: Excellent job! Sorry for the prank! :):):)

Comment: @g.kov When you used Inkscape then the way to get the picture in TeX document is more simple: export Inkscape result to PDF and include PDF image using `\pdfximage` (or similar tools like `\includegraphics`). No asymptote is needed.

Comment: @wipet: Sure, but what would be the fun in that?
The question is not serious anyway,
nevertheless it provides the opportunity
to show the way to access the geometry 
of the picture from the LaTeX world.
Look closely: the original picture
is not the same as the reconstructed one.
Changes are minimal here, but 
consider, for example, adding fish dimensions, area,
some text along the curve,
fish-shaped paragraph, adding shading, 
animation or even a blowing the fish into 3D image, you name it.

Comment: I'd be interested in the 3D version (PRC?).

Comment: @wipet One of your raw `\pdfliteral` designs is missing :)

Comment: @AlexG: yes, see added 3D fun version.

Comment: The 3D version actually deserves the bounty! :):):)

Answer (score 39):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,stackengine}

\begin{document}
\savestack\fish{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[fill=blue] (.5,0) rectangle (4,2);
        \draw[fill=red] (1,1) to[bend left=50] (3,1) to[bend left=50] (1,1);
        \draw[fill=red] (3,1) -- (3.5,1.5) -- (3.3,1) -- (3.5,.5) -- cycle;
        \draw[fill=white] (1.6,1.1) circle (.15cm); 
        \draw[fill=blue] (1.55,1.1) circle (.05cm);         
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\color{yellow}%
  \stackinset{c}{-2em}{c}{-.75em}{%
    \rotatebox{-150}{\scalebox{1}[.5]{\textcolor{white}{$\frown$}}}}{%
  \stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{%
    \scalebox{.7}{\rotatebox{-90}{$\frown\!\frown\!\frown$}}}{%
  \stackinset{c}{.7em}{c}{}{%
    \scalebox{.7}[.5]{\rotatebox{-90}{$\frown\!\frown\!\frown$}}}{%
  \stackinset{c}{1.3em}{c}{}{%
    \scalebox{.5}[.3]{\rotatebox{-90}{$\frown\!\frown\!\frown$}}}{%
  \stackinset{c}{2.6em}{c}{}{%
    \scalebox{.4}[.3]{\rotatebox{-90}{$\frown~\frown$}}}{%
  \stackinset{c}{2.9em}{c}{}{%
    \scalebox{.3}[.3]{\rotatebox{-90}{$\frown~~~~~~~~\frown$}}}{%
  \fish}}}}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Aw, don't be sad, turn that `\frown` upside down!

Comment: +1, very creative way of using `\frown`! See the edit of my question!

Comment: @CarLaTeX Thank you for the bounty, and the international lesson on what we call in the US "April Fools Day".  Here, we have no such fish connection, but pranks are the order of the day.

Comment: You're welcome. On Wikipedia they say _In 1508, French poet Eloy d'Amerval referred to a poisson d’avril (April fool, literally "Fish of April"), a possible reference to the holiday._ Hence I think it's connected to fishes also in France, it'd be interesting to know for which other countries is the same :):):)

Comment: @CarLaTeX Corroboration: http://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/april-fools-tradition-popularized, http://metro.co.uk/2017/03/30/where-does-april-fools-day-come-from-6542530/

Comment: :):):) confirmed by multiple sources :):):)

Comment: @CarLaTeX To steal from one source is plagiarism...to steal from many is research.

Answer (score 32):

A (poor) *mathematical fish*.

```
${\cdot}\kern -4pt {\subset}\kern -3pt {\rtimes}$
```

[image]

Comment: looks like a bomb

Comment: @AlexG, I agree. Specially like those from Super Mario game.

Comment: But I like it anyway, +1

Comment: ooh a Bullet Bill or a Banzai Bill. `:)`

Answer (score 29):

A [Metafish](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html), with fins...

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);

    u = 20;
path dorso, ventro;
dorso  = ((-1/4,0) .. (0,1/2) .. (1,9/8) .. (2,5/4) .. (4,1) .. (6,2/3) .. (7.5,17/16)) scaled u;
ventro = ((0,-1/3)..(1,-1)..(4.4,-1)..(6,-1/2)..(7.5,-17/16)) scaled u;

picture eye;
eye = image(
    fill fullcircle scaled 10 withcolor white;
    draw fullcircle scaled 10;
    fill fullcircle scaled 5 shifted 1/2(-1,1);
    unfill fullcircle scaled 1 shifted (-1,1);
    fill   fullcircle scaled 1/2 shifted (-2.73,2.73);
);

path tail[]; n=16;
for t=1 upto n-1:
    tail[t] = interpath(t/n,subpath(5,6) of dorso, subpath(3,4) of ventro);
    tail[t] := tail[t] shifted (3-sqrt(abs(ypart point 0 of tail[t])),0);
endfor

path body;
body = reverse ventro .. (1/8u,-1/8u) {left} .. (-1/4u,0) & dorso
    for i=1 upto n-1: .. point 1 of tail[i] {dir -40} endfor .. cycle; 

path a,b;
a = point 3   of dorso {direction 3 of dorso rotated 72} .. point 3   of dorso shifted (1/4u,1/2u+normaldeviate);
b = point 4.5 of dorso {direction 4.5 of dorso rotated 90}     .. point 4.5 of dorso shifted (1/3u,3/4u+normaldeviate);

path f[];
for t=0 upto 32: f[t] = subpath(0,7/8-(t**5/4)/512+1/64 normaldeviate) of interpath(t/32,a,b); endfor
for t=0 upto 32: draw f[t]; endfor
draw point 1 of f[0] for t=1 upto 32: .. {dir 60} point 1 of f[t] endfor;

path a,b;
a = point 1.5   of ventro {direction 2 of ventro rotated -72} 
 .. point 1.5   of ventro shifted (1/4u,-1/2u+normaldeviate);
b = point 3 of ventro {direction 3 of ventro rotated -90}     
 .. point 3 of ventro shifted (1/3u,-3/4u+normaldeviate);

path f[];
for t=0 upto 16: f[t] = subpath(0,7/8+1/64 normaldeviate) of interpath(t/32,a,b); endfor
for t=0 upto 16: draw f[t]; endfor
draw point 1 of f[0] for t=1 upto 16: .. {dir 60} point 1 of f[t] endfor;

fill body withcolor 3/4[1/3[blue,green],white];
draw body;
for t=1 upto n-1:   draw tail[t]; endfor
draw eye rotated -10 shifted (1/2u,1/4u);
endfig;
end.
```

Comment: I like this fish best among the fish here. What a pity that it is not tikzed.

Comment: Thank you!  TikZ is not *always* the best drawing tool... I do my best to show that Metapost still has some useful features.  It's also a much more interesting and entertaining language...  In this drawing I found MP's `interpath` and `normaldeviate` useful.

Answer (score 24):

Let us add a `shapepar` answer, including ducks too:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{shapepar}

\def\fishpar#1{\shapepar{\fishshape}#1\par}
\def\fishshape{%
{25.6127}%
{0.857843}b{50.6127}\\%
{1.59314}t{50}{0.40266}\\%
{1.71569}t{49.895}{0.47269}\\%
{2.32843}b{22.1814}t{49.3697}{0.793652}\\%
{2.45098}t{21.3235}{1.71569}t{49.2647}{0.857843}\\%
{2.57353}t{20.3431}{3.43137}t{49.183}{0.89869}\\%
{2.69608}t{19.7304}{4.77941}t{49.1013}{0.939545}\\%
{2.81863}t{19.1176}{5.94363}t{49.0196}{0.980392}\\%
{2.94118}t{18.5049}{7.10784}t{48.9379}{1.02124}\\%
{3.06373}t{17.8922}{8.33333}t{48.8562}{1.06209}\\%
{3.18627}t{16.9118}{9.92647}t{48.7745}{1.10294}\\%
{3.43137}t{16.1765}{11.3971}t{48.6111}{1.18464}\\%
{3.55392}t{15.8088}{12.1324}t{48.5294}{1.22549}\\%
{3.67647}t{15.4412}{12.8676}t{48.4314}{1.28268}\\%
{3.92157}t{14.7059}{14.3382}t{48.2353}{1.39706}\\%
{4.28922}t{13.9706}{15.9314}t{47.9412}{1.58613}\\%
{4.41176}t{13.7255}{16.4216}t{47.8431}{1.64916}\\%
{4.65686}t{13.2353}{17.402}t{47.6471}{1.77521}\\%
{4.77941}t{12.9902}{17.8309}t{47.549}{1.83824}\\%
{4.90196}t{12.7451}{18.2598}t{47.4673}{1.8893}\\%
{5.14706}t{12.2549}{19.1176}t{47.3039}{1.99142}\\%
{5.51471}t{11.5196}{20.5882}t{47.0588}{2.14461}\\%
{5.7598}t{11.0294}{21.5686}t{46.8954}{2.24673}\\%
{5.88235}t{10.7843}{22.0588}t{46.8137}{2.3012}\\%
{6.25}t{10.2328}{23.125}t{46.5686}{2.4646}\\%
{6.4951}t{9.8652}{23.8358}t{46.3904}{2.58838}\\%
{6.61765}t{9.68137}{24.2647}t{46.3012}{2.65028}\\%
{6.86275}t{9.19118}{25.2451}t{46.123}{2.77406}\\%
{7.23039}t{8.45588}{26.5319}t{45.8556}{2.95975}\\%
{7.35294}t{8.2598}{26.9118}t{45.7665}{3.02164}\\%
{7.59804}t{7.86765}{27.6307}t{45.5882}{3.14542}\\%
{7.84314}t{7.47549}{28.3497}t{45.41}{3.26921}\\%
{7.96569}t{7.31209}{28.6765}t{45.3209}{3.33111}\\%
{8.08823}t{7.14869}{29.0033}t{45.2317}{3.38959}\\%
{8.21078}t{6.98529}{5.26961}st{12.2549}{24.1013}t{45.1426}{3.44808}\\%
{8.21078}t{6.98529}{4.77941}t{12.2549}{24.1013}t{45.1426}{3.44808}\\%
{8.33333}t{6.8219}{4.57516}t{12.6225}{23.9379}t{45.0535}{3.50657}\\%
{8.45588}t{6.6585}{4.49346}t{12.8676}{23.8971}t{44.9643}{3.56506}\\%
{8.57843}t{6.4951}{4.41176}t{13.1127}{23.8562}t{44.8752}{3.62355}\\%
{8.70098}t{6.29902}{4.36274}t{13.3578}{23.8154}t{44.7861}{3.68204}\\%
{8.82353}t{6.10294}{4.49755}t{13.4191}{23.9583}t{44.697}{3.74053}\\%
{8.94608}t{5.90686}{4.63235}t{13.4804}{24.0721}t{44.6078}{3.79902}\\%
{9.06863}t{5.71078}{4.58333}t{13.7255}{24.0021}t{44.5261}{3.86321}\\%
{9.19118}t{5.51471}{4.71814}t{13.7868}{24.1159}t{44.4444}{3.92741}\\%
{9.31373}t{5.34314}{4.82843}t{13.848}{24.2297}t{44.3627}{3.9916}\\%
{9.55882}t{5}{5.04902}t{13.9706}{24.4573}t{44.1993}{4.11998}\\%
{9.68137}t{4.82843}{5.22059}t{13.9706}{24.6324}t{44.1176}{4.18417}\\%
{9.80392}t{4.65686}{5.39216}t{13.9706}{24.8162}t{44.0359}{4.24836}\\%
{9.92647}t{4.47304}{5.57598}t{13.9706}{25}t{43.9542}{4.30964}\\%
{10.049}t{4.28922}{5.69853}t{14.0319}{25.1225}t{43.8726}{4.37091}\\%
{10.1716}t{4.10539}{5.82108}t{14.0931}{25.2451}t{43.785}{4.43803}\\%
{10.2941}t{3.92157}{6.0049}t{14.0931}{25.4289}t{43.6975}{4.50514}\\%
{10.4167}t{3.77451}{6.15196}t{14.0931}{25.6127}t{43.6099}{4.57224}\\%
{10.5392}t{3.62745}{6.36029}t{14.0319}{25.8374}t{43.5224}{4.63936}\\%
{10.6618}t{3.48039}{6.56863}t{13.9706}{26.0621}t{43.4349}{4.72689}\\%
{10.9069}t{3.18627}{6.86275}t{13.9706}{26.3889}t{43.2598}{4.90196}\\%
{11.0294}t{3.00245}{7.04657}t{13.9706}{26.5523}t{43.1723}{4.9895}\\%
{11.152}t{2.81863}{7.29167}t{13.9093}{26.777}t{43.0847}{5.07703}\\%
{11.2745}t{2.6348}{7.53676}t{13.848}{27.0527}t{42.9972}{5.16457}\\%
{11.3971}t{2.45098}{7.78186}t{13.7868}{27.3284}t{42.9097}{5.2521}\\%
{11.5196}t{2.28758}{8.00654}t{13.7255}{27.6042}t{42.8221}{5.33964}\\%
{11.6422}t{2.12418}{8.41503}t{13.4804}{28.0637}t{42.7346}{5.42717}\\%
{11.7647}t{1.96078}{8.63971}t{13.4191}{28.3088}t{42.6471}{5.51471}\\%
{11.8873}t{1.79739}{8.86438}t{13.3578}{28.5539}t{42.5245}{5.63725}\\%
{12.0098}t{1.63399}{9.27288}t{13.1127}{28.9828}t{42.402}{5.7598}\\%
{12.1324}t{1.47059}{9.68137}t{12.8676}{29.4118}jt{42.2794}{5.88235}\\%
{12.2549}t{1.29902}{10.098}t{12.6225}{35.5392}\\%
{12.3775}t{1.12745}{10.6373}t{12.2549}{35.9069}\\%
{12.3775}t{1.12745}{10.6373}jt{11.7647}{36.3971}\\%
{12.7451}t{0.612745}{47.5082}\\%
{13.4804}t{0.980392}{47.0588}\\%
{13.9706}t{1.71569}{46.4052}\\%
{14.2157}t{2.04248}{46.1193}\\%
{14.7059}t{2.69608}{45.5474}\\%
{14.951}t{3.10458}{45.1797}\\%
{15.1961}t{3.51307}{38.7663}st{42.2794}{6.0049}\\%
{15.4412}t{3.92157}{38.0637}t{42.4837}{5.80065}\\%
{15.6863}t{4.27171}{37.4195}t{42.6879}{5.5964}\\%
{15.8088}t{4.44678}{37.0973}t{42.79}{5.52492}\\%
{15.9314}t{4.62185}{36.7384}t{42.8922}{5.45343}\\%
{16.299}t{5.14706}{35.6618}t{43.1373}{5.30025}\\%
{16.6667}t{5.67227}{34.5483}t{43.3824}{5.14706}\\%
{16.9118}t{6.02241}{33.806}t{43.5458}{5.01867}\\%
{17.0343}t{6.19748}{33.3859}t{43.6275}{4.95448}\\%
{17.1569}t{6.37255}{32.9657}t{43.7347}{4.86476}\\%
{17.2794}t{6.54762}{32.5455}t{43.8419}{4.77504}\\%
{17.5245}t{6.89776}{31.8277}t{44.0564}{4.59559}\\%
{17.7696}t{7.2479}{31.1099}t{44.2708}{4.42198}\\%
{18.0147}t{7.59804}{30.3922}t{44.4853}{4.24836}\\%
{18.2598}t{7.9902}{29.6324}t{44.6814}{4.09314}\\%
{18.6275}t{8.57843}{28.3088}t{44.9755}{3.89093}\\%
{18.75}t{8.76225}{27.8799}t{45.0735}{3.82353}\\%
{19.1176}t{9.31373}{26.7402}t{45.3676}{3.62132}\\%
{19.2402}t{9.49755}{26.3603}t{45.4657}{3.55392}\\%
{19.3627}t{9.68137}{25.9804}t{45.5637}{3.4909}\\%
{19.6078}t{10.049}{25.0613}t{45.7598}{3.36485}\\%
{19.8529}t{10.4779}{24.0809}t{45.9559}{3.23879}\\%
{20.098}t{10.9069}{23.1618}t{46.152}{3.11274}\\%
{20.4657}t{11.6422}{21.6912}t{46.4461}{2.8799}\\%
{20.5882}t{11.8873}{21.1397}t{46.5352}{2.8112}\\%
{20.8333}t{12.3775}{20.0368}t{46.7135}{2.6738}\\%
{20.9559}t{12.6225}{19.4853}t{46.8026}{2.61968}\\%
{21.0784}t{12.8676}{18.9542}t{46.8917}{2.56557}\\%
{21.3235}t{13.7255}{17.5245}t{47.07}{2.45735}\\%
{21.6912}t{14.5833}{15.9314}t{47.3373}{2.29501}\\%
{21.8137}t{14.9101}{15.3595}t{47.4265}{2.23652}\\%
{22.0588}t{15.5637}{13.9706}t{47.6443}{2.07993}\\%
{22.3039}t{16.6667}{11.8873}t{47.8622}{1.92334}\\%
{22.549}t{17.402}{10.049}t{48.0801}{1.76675}\\%
{22.6716}t{17.7696}{9.06863}t{48.189}{1.68845}\\%
{22.7941}t{18.5049}{7.72059}t{48.2979}{1.61016}\\%
{22.9167}t{19.1176}{6.4951}t{48.4069}{1.53186}\\%
{23.0392}t{19.7304}{5.26961}t{48.5022}{1.46718}\\%
{23.1618}t{20.8333}{3.18627}t{48.5975}{1.40251}\\%
{23.1618}t{21.5686}{1.47059}t{48.5975}{1.40251}\\%
{23.2843}e{22.3039}t{48.6928}{1.33783}\\%
{23.652}t{48.9788}{1.14379}\\%
{24.0196}t{49.2647}{0.949755}\\%
{24.6324}t{49.7753}{0.592322}\\%
{24.7549}t{49.8775}{0.490196}\\%
{25.4902}e{50.3676}%
}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\duck}{\prg_replicate:nn {400}{duck~}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\fishpar{\duck}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: Quack!]

I am hungry. `:)`

Answer (score 19):

## Basic

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-fun}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(6,4)
    \psFish[fillstyle=slope]
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Advanced

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-vehicle,pst-fun}

\def\V{\rput{20}(7.7,.5){\psscalebox{-1.3 1.3}{\psFish[fillstyle=slope]}}}
\def\F{cos(x)/2+x/3}

\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {0,0.2,...,8}{
\begin{pspicture}(-1,0)(11,6)   
    \psplot{-1}{11}{\F}
    \psVehicle[vehicle=\SelfDefinedVehicle,ownvehicle=\V,showSlope=false,frontwheel=\SpokesWheelB,backwheel=\SpokesWheelA,rB=1.2,rF=0.7,d=4.8]{.5}{\i}{\F}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 17):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\tikzset{Pacman/.pic={
\fill (0,0)  to[out={1.75*#1},in={180-0.25*#1}] ({0.92*#1}:2)
 to[out={-180+0.25*#1},in={1.75*#1},looseness=0.5] (1,0) 
 to[out={-1.75*#1},in={180-0.25*#1},looseness=0.5] ({-0.92*#1}:2) 
 to [out={-180+0.25*#1},in={-1.75*#1}] cycle;
\shadedraw[ball color=yellow,thick] 
(0,0)  to[out={1.75*#1},in={180-0.25*#1}] ({0.92*#1}:2)
 arc({0.92*#1}:{360-0.92*#1}:2) to [out={-180+0.25*#1},in={-1.75*#1}]
  cycle;
\fill ({0.3-0.01*#1},1) circle (0.3);
  }
}
\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {0,...,20}
{\pgfmathsetmacro{\myangle}{60-5*abs(\i-10)}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
%\begin{scope}[xshift={-(6.5-0.4*\i)*1cm},scale=2]
\fill (0,0)  to[out={1.75*\myangle},in={180-0.25*\myangle}] ({0.92*\myangle}:2)
to[out={-180+0.25*\myangle},in={1.75*\myangle},looseness=0.5] (1,0) 
to[out={-1.75*\myangle},in={180-0.25*\myangle},looseness=0.5]
({-0.92*\myangle}:2) to [out={-180+0.25*\myangle},in={-1.75*\myangle}]   cycle;
%\end{scope}
\pic[xscale=-1] at (5-0.30*\i,0) {Pacman=\myangle};
%\begin{scope}[xshift={-(6.5-0.4*\i)*1cm},scale=2]
\shade[postaction={path fading=east,fill=white}] [ball color=yellow,thick] 
(0,0)  to[out={1.75*\myangle},in={180-0.25*\myangle}] ({0.92*\myangle}:2)
 arc({0.92*\myangle}:{360-0.92*\myangle}:2) to [out={-180+0.25*\myangle},in={-1.75*\myangle}]
  cycle;
\fill ({0.35-0.015*\myangle},1) circle (0.3);
\shade[postaction={path fading=west,fill=white}]
[postaction={path fading=west,fading angle=45,fill=blue,opacity=.5}] 
[top color=red!20,bottom color=red,opacity=0.6] (0,2) to[out=180,in=20] (-4,1) to[out=-160,in=-20] (-5,1)
to[out=160,in=-45] (-6,1.8) to[out=-80,in=80] (-6,-1.6)
to[out=45,in=-160] (-5,-0.8) to[out=20,in=160] (-4,-0.8)
to[out=-20,in=180] (0,-2) to[out=160,in=-160] cycle;
%\end{scope}
\path[use as bounding box](-8,-2) rectangle (4,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. When the killer fish opens its mouth to the maximum it seems exaggerated `:0`.

Answer (score 8):

**An alphish**

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\alphish}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1em,y=1ex, every node/.style={inner sep=0 cm, outer sep=0 cm}]
    \node {\(\alpha\)} node at (-0.1,0.2) {.} node at (-0.1,-0.1) {-};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {\(\circ\)} node at (-0.2,0.1) {\(\circ\)} node at (0,0.3) {\(\circ\)} node at (-0.1,0.5) {\(\circ\)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\Huge\alphish\LARGE\alphish\normalsize\alphish\alphish\alphish
\end{document}\
```

[image: Four small fishes made with the alpha symbol]
[image: (\hbar=\frac{h}{2\pi}) \quad and \quad (\alphish=\frac{\alpha}{2\pi})]

Answer (score 3):

You want a fish? I'll give you three!

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
$a \quad \alpha \quad \propto$
\end{document}
```

and the result looks like this :)

[image]