# Table with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, color, nodes

I should create a table like the one here as example. I think that the best way to do a table like this one is generate some labels and use them to colorize the nodes in order to make it more automatic. First column are categorized colors and right column are a color spectrum. My question is if you have to face a problem like this one which tools from TikZ would you use to generate such table. I started to code the table in TikZ but I was defining everything: The position of the nodes, all the line intersecting points to create the lines afterwards. The code gets huge, nasty, and horrible to check if i I've placed the colors properly.

Therefore, do you have any suggestions of how would you do this job?

[image]

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30168/improving-tikz-user-interface, I think the UI concept offered there would easily be twisted for this diagram and would provide cleaner code.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This can give you a starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}

\definecolor{redi}{RGB}{255,38,0}
\definecolor{redii}{RGB}{200,50,30}
\definecolor{yellowi}{RGB}{255,251,0}
\definecolor{bluei}{RGB}{0,150,255}
\definecolor{blueii}{RGB}{135,247,210}
\definecolor{blueiii}{RGB}{91,205,250}
\definecolor{blueiv}{RGB}{115,244,253}
\definecolor{bluev}{RGB}{1,58,215}
\definecolor{orangei}{RGB}{240,143,50}
\definecolor{yellowii}{RGB}{222,247,100}
\definecolor{greeni}{RGB}{166,247,166}

\tikzset{ 
table/.style={
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={rectangle,draw=black,text width=1.25ex,align=center},
  text depth=0.25ex,
  text height=1ex,
  nodes in empty cells
  },
texto/.style={font=\footnotesize\sffamily},
title/.style={font=\small\sffamily}
}


\newcommand\CellText[2]{%
  \node[texto,left=of mat#1,anchor=east]
  at (mat#1.west)
  {#2};
}

\newcommand\SlText[2]{%
  \node[texto,left=of mat#1,anchor=west,rotate=75]
  at ([xshift=3ex]mat#1.north)
  {#2};
}

\newcommand\RowTitle[2]{%
\node[title,left=6.3cm of mat#1,anchor=west]
  at (mat#1.north west)
  {#2};
}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance =0pt and 0.5cm]

\matrix[table] (mat11) 
{
|[fill=redi]| & & & \\
|[fill=redi]| & & & \\
|[fill=redi]| & & & \\
};
\matrix[table,right=of mat11] (mat12) 
{
|[fill=orangei]| & |[fill=yellowii]| & |[fill=blueii]| & |[fill=blueiii]| \\
& |[fill=blueii]| & |[fill=greeni]| & |[fill=blueiv]| \\
& & |[fill=bluev]| & |[fill=blueiii]| \\
};
\matrix[table,below=of mat11] (mat21) 
{
|[fill=redi]| & & & \\
|[fill=redi]| & & & \\
|[fill=yellowi]| & & & \\
|[fill=yellowi]| & & & \\
};
\matrix[table,below=of mat12] (mat22) 
{
|[fill=bluev!95]| & & |[fill=yellowii]| & |[fill=orangei!80]| \\
& |[fill=yellowii]| & |[fill=bluev!80]| & |[fill=blueiii]| \\
|[fill=redii]| & |[fill=blueiii!80]| & & |[fill=bluev]| \\
|[fill=bluev]| & & |[fill=blueiii!80]| & |[fill=bluev]| \\
};
\matrix[table,below=of mat21] (mat31) 
{
|[fill=redi]| & & & \\
|[fill=bluei]| & & & \\
};
\matrix[table,below=of mat22] (mat32) 
{
|[fill=bluev]| & & |[fill=redii]| & |[fill=redii!90!black]| \\
|[fill=redii!90]| & |[fill=redii!75!black]| & |[fill=bluev]| & |[fill=bluev!80!black]| \\
};

\SlText{11-1-1}{Fibroadenoma [xx]}
\SlText{11-1-2}{Simple Cyst}
\SlText{11-1-3}{Complex Cyst}
\SlText{11-1-4}{Papilloma}

\SlText{12-1-1}{CDI}
\SlText{12-1-2}{CLI}
\SlText{12-1-3}{FA}
\SlText{12-1-4}{Cyst}

\RowTitle{11}{Background echotexture};
\CellText{11-1-1}{Homogeneous adipose-echotexture};
\CellText{11-2-1}{Homogeneous fibroglandular-echotexture};
\CellText{11-3-1}{Hoterogeneous};

\RowTitle{21}{Mass shape};
\CellText{21-1-1}{Oval};
\CellText{21-2-1}{Round};
\CellText{21-3-1}{Irregular};

\RowTitle{31}{Mass orientation};
\CellText{21-4-1}{Lobular};
\CellText{31-1-1}{Parallel to skin};
\CellText{31-2-1}{Non-parallel to skin};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 17):

You don't *have* to use Tikz;-)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,array,graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\zz}p{1em}|}
\def\zzz{\textcolor{\thiscol}{\leaders\vrule height1em\hskip1em}\kern\z@\ignorespaces}

\def\zz\ignorespaces#1{%
\def\thiscol{white}%
\if S#1\expandafter\szz
\else\if R#1\def\thiscol{red}%
\else\if Y#1\def\thiscol{yellow}%
\else\if B#1\def\thiscol{blue}%
\else\if X#1\def\thiscol{black}%
\else#1\fi\fi\fi\fi
\expandafter\zzz
\fi}
\def\szz{\afterassignment\@szz\count@0}
\def\@szz{\edef\thiscol{mycolor-\the\count@}\zzz}

\definecolor{mycolor-1}{rgb}{.8,.4,.6}
\definecolor{mycolor-20}{rgb}{.7,.9,.6}
\definecolor{mycolor-5}{rgb}{.2,.4,.6}
\definecolor{mycolor-4}{rgb}{.2,.7,.3}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{0}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{2em}}r@{\hspace{2pt}}|ZZZZ@{\hspace{1cm}}ZZZZ}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\rlap{\rotatebox{60}{something}}}&
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\rlap{\rotatebox{60}{something else}}}&
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\rlap{\rotatebox{60}{ho hum}}}&
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\rlap{\rotatebox{60}{more stuff}}}&
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\rlap{\rotatebox{60}{and more}}}&
\multicolumn{1}{l@{\hspace{1cm}}}{\rlap{\rotatebox{60}{interesting column}}}&
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\rlap{\rotatebox{60}{ABC}}}&
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\rlap{\rotatebox{60}{XYZ}}}&
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\rlap{\rotatebox{60}{EED}}}&
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\rlap{\rotatebox{60}{JHY}}}\\
\hline
stuff& foo &R&&&&  S1 &&&\\\hline
stuff& foo &Y&&&&  S20 &&S5&\\\hline
stuff& foo &B&&&&  S5 &&S1&\\\hline
stuff& foo &X&&&&  S4 &&&S20\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13):

You don’t have to use TikZ (but you can).

I would use either [`pgfplotstable`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplotstable) (but that would make a hard start) or at least the [`collcell`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/collcell) package to make the creation easier.

If all you want is colored cells define the needed colors with a distinctive name with `\colorlet` or `\definecolor` and use that as the cell content that is than grabbed by `\collectcell` and given to `\myBox` as an argument.

In this example, this is simply used to use a `\cellcolor` but can be provided to TikZ that draws a rectangle, or could be the name of a key (think [`pgfkeys`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfkeys)) that in turns can do anything (`\cellcolor`,  simply text, TikZ).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,collcell}
\newcommand*{\myBox}[1]{\cellcolor{col@#1}}
\colorlet{col@a}{red}  \colorlet{col@b}{blue}
\colorlet{col@c}{cyan} \colorlet{col@d}{black}
\colorlet{col@e}{green}\colorlet{col@f}{red!50!yellow}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\collectcell\myBox}#1<{\endcollectcell}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l C{c} C{c} p{.5cm} C{c} C{c}}
    Background Echotexture & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Head1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Head2} & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Head3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Head4} \\
    Foo                    & a                         & b                         & & c                         & d                         \\
    Bar                    & e                         & a                         & & d                         & f
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

## A little bit of TikZ

Here is a more sophisticated approach.

TikZ is used to draw the boxes, nothing more.

`pgfkeys` is used to define a few simply styles like `common` and `probable`.
The `.` style is a minimalistic style that only draws the border bot doesn’t use any filling. The `.unknown` key is set up so that you can use any color that is then used as an argument to the `box` style; but I recommend defining styles at least for common cells (the colors in the boxes on the right side surely mean something).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,collcell}
\newcommand*{\cellset}{\pgfqkeys{/cell}}
\newcommand*{\myCell}{\cellset}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\collectcell\myCell}#1<{\endcollectcell}}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{overlay linewidth/.code=\tikz@addmode{\tikzset{overlay}}}
\cellset{.unknown/.code={\edef\pgfkeys@temp{\noexpand\cellset{box=\pgfkeyscurrentname}}\pgfkeys@temp}}
\makeatother
\cellset{
  head/.code=\rlap{\rotatebox{60}{#1}}\hspace*{1.2em},
  myCell/.style={
    draw=black,
    overlay linewidth,
    inner sep=+0pt,
    outer sep=+0pt,
    anchor=center,
    fill={#1},
    minimum size=+1.7em},
  box/.code={%
    \tikz[baseline=-1ex]
      \node[/cell/myCell={#1}]{};},
  box/.default=none,
  ./.style={box},
  @define/.style args={#1:#2}{#1/.style={box=#2}},
  @define/.list={%
    not present:black,  possible:cyan,
    probable:   yellow, common:  red,
    o:          orange, y:       yellow}
  }
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\footnotesize}r *4{C{c} @{}} @{\hspace*{.5cm}} *4{C{c} @{}}}
                                               & head=Fibroadenoma [xx] & head=Simply Cyst & head=Complex Cist & head=Pailloma & head=CDI & head=CLI     & head=FA & head=Cyst      \\[1em]
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Background Echotexture} &                        &                  &                   &               &          &              &         &  \\
               Homogeneous adipose-echotexture & common                 & .                & .                 & .             & o        & y            & .       & .              \\
        Homogeneous fibroglandular-echotexture & common                 & .                & .                 & .             & blue     & .            & .       & .              \\
               Homogeneous adipose-echotexture & common                 & .                & .                 & .             & .        & .            & .       & .              \\[1em]
                \multicolumn{1}{l}{Mass Shape} &                        &                  &                   &               &          &              &         &  \\
                                          Oval & common                 & .                & .                 & .             & .        & .            & .       & o              \\
                                         Round & common                 & .                & .                 & .             & .        & .            & .       & .              \\
                                     Irregular & probable               & .                & .                 & .             & .        & .            & .       & .              \\
                                       Iobular & probable               & .                & .                 & .             & .        & .            & .       & .              \\[1em]
          \multicolumn{1}{l}{Mass Orientation} &                        &                  &                   &               &          &              &         &  \\
                              Parallel to skin & common                 & .                & .                 & .             & blue     & .            & red     & red!50!black   \\
                          Non-parallel to skin & possible               & .                & .                 & .             & red      & red!30!black & blue    & blue!50!black 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I knew you wouldn't be able to resist tikz in the end.